# Running PMD for C++ project in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, pmd

I am using eclipse based development IDE called STM32Cube IDE V1.5.1. I have installed PMD plugin into same. PMD Plugin version 4.24.x & PMD Version 6.35.x.
On most of the links it was found that PMD can be used for java projects for code analysis however I could not find any information whether it can be used for C++ project or not.
If it can be used for C++ project can anyone direct me to the link.
or can anyone pass on the information on how to configure PMD tool for code analysis for C++ project.

Best Regards,
Satish

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433632/is-there-a-findbugs-and-or-pmd-equivalent-for-c-c

Answer (score 1):

PMD doesn't support C++ (or C) for static code analysis. You can only search for duplicated code (the tool "CPD") which is also included in PMD.

CPD: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html

This tool can be run from within eclipse (with the Eclipse PMD Plugin installed) via the menu "Find suspect cut and paste...".

For the full supported languages of PMD see https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cli_reference.html#supported-languages