# Combining callcatcher and cmake

Tags: c, cmake, linker, fortran, unused-functions

My aim is to find procedures in our large and old codebase that are never called.
Our [code](https://github.com/ghb24/NECI_STABLE), called neci, is mostly Fortran and some C/C++ code.
From the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091397/is-there-a-way-to-get-warned-about-unused-functions) I stumbled over the wonderful tool [callcatcher](https://github.com/caolanm/callcatcher) but I have difficulties in combining it with cmake.

When I use `callcatcher` by compiling manually a bunch of Fortran files, everything works correctly and finds unused procedures.

Now I wanted to embed this tool into our `cmake` compilation process and used.

```sh
cmake \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
    -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=mpifort -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mpicxx \
    -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=callcatcher -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=callcatcher -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=callcatcher \
    -DCMAKE_Fortran_LINKER_LAUNCHER=callcatcher -DCMAKE_C_LINKER_LAUNCHER=callcatcher -DCMAKE_CXX_LINKER_LAUNCHER=callcatcher \
     ~/code/neci
```

The computer then warns about:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_Fortran_LINKER_LAUNCHER
```

And indeed when I compile with `VERBOSE=3 make -j neci` I see that files are correctly compiled with `callcatcher` but the linking step does not prepend the call with `callcatcher`.

My questions are:

1. How can I force `cmake` to prepend the linker command with `callcatcher`?
2. If the first question hides an XY problem, how can I solve my original aim of finding uncalled procedures without `callcatcher`.

My cmake version is 3.21.3.

Comment: According to CMake documentation, the variable [CMAKE_<LANG>_LINKER_LAUNCHER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINKER_LAUNCHER.html) affects on the property [<LANG>_LINKER_LAUNCHER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_LINKER_LAUNCHER.html), which in turn exists only for C, CXX, OBJC, and OBJCXX languages. So CMake doesn't support `CMAKE_Fortran_LINKER_LAUNCHER` variable.