# gcc linker get list of unused objects

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I want to identify unused object files in a large C application with many libraries. The project has grown a lot over time and now I want to search for libraries that are not used anymore, so that I can remove them from the dependency file. Is it possible with the gcc linker to identify any object that is not used?

For example, if I compile an application with gcc and let's say none of the symbols/functions of library2 are used. Is there any way to get the info about which objects are not linked in?

```
gcc library1.o library2.o main.o -o main.elf
```

I know that gcc has the compiler and linker flags to remove unused symbols:

```
-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections
```

However this way I don't know which of the objects were removed by gcc. It would be perfect if gcc has an option to get a list of objects which were not linked into the application.

Just to mention: I need it on object file basis not on function/symbol basis!

Does anyone know such an option for gcc?

Comment: So you could just look, which `.o` files you can find after compiling and compare to your sourcefiles.
I don't know for sure, just an idea...

Comment: Take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4449936/3436922). It could help.

Comment: @R. Joiny Yes it is. I am already using the flags -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections which removes unused code. However this way I cannot identify the objects to remove and them and tidy up my buildsystem

Comment: @LPs: I already read this post, but I thought of an gcc option to get the list automatically...

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible with [tag:gcc]. Another interesting post is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091397/is-there-a-way-to-get-warned-about-unused-functions), but probably you already know it.

Answer (score 3):

> For example, if I compile an application with gcc and let's say none of the symbols/functions of library2 are used. Is there any way to get the info about which objects are not linked in?
>
> `gcc library1.o library2.o main.o -o main.elf`

With above command, `library2.o` *will* be linked in even if none of the code from it is ever used. To understand why, read [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) or [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

It is true that *if* you compile code in `library2.o` with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` *and* link with `-Wl,-gc-sections`, then all of the code and data from `library2.o` will be GC'd out, but that is not the command you gave.

Presumably, you are more interested in what happens if you use libraries as libraries:

```
gcc main.o -o main.elf -lrary1 -lrary2
```

In that case, if none of the code from `library2` is referenced, the linker will not pull it into the link.

There is no way to ask the linker for list of things it *didn't* use, but (if you are using GNU-ld) there is a way to ask it for a list of objects it *did* use: the `-M` or `-Map` option. Once you know what objects are used, it's a simple matter of subtracting used objects from all objects used while linking to get the list that is not used.

**Update:**

Gold linker supports `--print-symbol-counts FILENAME` option, which can also be helpful here. It prints defined and *used* symbol counts. For `library2.a`, it should print `$num_defined 0`, the `0` indicating that none of the objects from `library2.a` were actually used.

Comment: You are right, my command was wrong, sorry that it was not accurate. I also thought of doing a diff between the built objects and linked objects, I only thought that gcc already has some builtin flags helping me doing that.

Comment: Hi @Employed Russian, can you explain how to extract the list of used object files from the generated `output.map` file? Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @K.Mulier Unfortunately the `output.map` is written for human consumption, not machine post-processing. You can use `grep`, `awk` or any other text processing tool to get the list from it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My `output.map` file is 30.000 lines long... All I am looking for is a list of object files that are used (and a list of object files that is unused). But I don't know where to start looking in the file...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [callcatcher](https://www.skynet.ie/~caolan/Packages/callcatcher.html)

This compiles your program into assembly and extracts obvious references from the assembly output. I guess that is exactly what you are searching for. (Note due to the fact it analyzes assembler output it will only work on x86 platforms)

Note *callcatcher* ignores virtual functions (for some good reasons), so it will not directly allow you to analyse those.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know this tool, but it looks interesting. I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi @tofro. Looks very interesting. It would be great if it could work on code written for ARM microcontrollers...