# How can I scan C++ source codes to purge it?

Tags: c#, c++

Suppose there is an extensive C++ framework. This framework has multiple modules. I need to develop a tool that can scan all *.cpp, *.h, *.hpp files in the framework, isolate files relevant to one executable, and then remove all source code from those files that are not needed for compiling a specified executable.

**For example,** the framework has modules for querying relational databases, Document databases, Key-value stores, Column-oriented databases, and Graph databases.

I want to isolate only those files relevant to relational databases, and then I want to remove all those codes not used in relational databases.

Say the framework has a file `format_string.hpp.` This file contains 73 functions that can format strings in various ways. However, the relational database-related module uses only 15 functions from that file. So, I want to remove the rest of the 58 functions from that file.

**Note:** I often need to study C++ source codes and translate/convert that source code into other programming languages. This tool will help me understand the algorithms.

The deletion/purge is not permanent. It is only for learning purposes. This is about reducing the amount of source code for further manual inspection.

**Question:**

I have implemented the file-isolation part using C#.

However, I don't know how to implement the second part.

Do I need to use regex? Or do I need a lexer and a parser?

Comment: cross-site duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/444482 which has insightful comments

Comment: What is the root issue? Are target binaries too big? Then read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/how-to-remove-unused-c-c-symbols-with-gcc-and-ld

Comment: @PiotrNycz, No. The root issue is the source code base is too big, poorly designed, and messy.

Comment: https://www.cppdepend.com/

Comment: If you can get things to compile and link, you could instruct the linker to remove unused symbols. With optimizations enabled (enough inlining), I would hope that this removes most functions. Compare the list of symbols with a run without removed symbols, and you have at least a partial list of what you want. See these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38048977/3740047 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/how-to-remove-unused-c-c-symbols-with-gcc-and-ld

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is, with some limitations, possible in C# using reflection, but for C++, you basically need to write a compiler for this. If the compiler is used with optimizations enabled, it does that for you and strips unused code, but that's the very last step of compilation (or rather, linkage). Doing this by pure textual analysis is almost impossible, since there are too many ways how code can be referenced even without literally mentioning it (e.g. macros or virtual functions).

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much what code coverage tool were made to do.
Have a look at [OpenCppCoverage](https://github.com/OpenCppCoverage/OpenCppCoverage/) for an openSource example of such a tool.

You can feed your executable into it, and it will mark all code that is actually reachable by that executable:
[image: SourceCoverage.png]

Comment: Coverage is not as same as dead code elimination.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions describing using analysis tools or relying on the compiler to strip unlinked code will work if you are compiling the code using your library at the same time, but would not work if you are making these into a dll and only using some entry points. If that is the case, the compiler or analyzer needs to look at everything because it doesn't know what entry point is going to be used.

If this is the case, and you want to rely on the compiler, you could remove entry points that you dont intend to use, and compare binary sizes.

If you would still like to write your own tool, I would imagine you would need to provide it the entry points you want to use, and then recursively add their definitions to your 'required code'. You could first scan the file and break it into blocks defined by {parens}, and grab the identifier for the block (class name, function name, etc). Starting from your entry point, scan through the block, and if their are any symbols not already in your set, add them, and add their connected block to the end of a list of lines to parse. After parsing every line, you should be left with a set of blocks that are used, and you can mark the rest as unneeded.

There will be lots of exceptions and other things to look at, such as static variables, following includes to make sure the block is actually the one being used, etc, but this seems like a good starting point