# Identifying Unused Functions in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function, dead-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding “dead code” in a large C++ legacy application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380153/finding-dead-code-in-a-large-c-legacy-application)

My project has a lots of C source files each with a lots of global functions.  Many of these are no longer referenced by any caller at all.  Is there a simple way to identify which of these functions are not referenced by anyone at all?

The map file generated by VC seems to be useful.  But I am not sure exactly how/when a function name is listed in the map file.

Comment: Manually delete and recompile the code for the doubtful functions.

Comment: Actually, I am interested in learning how the map file generated by the VC linker can be used for this purpose. (since it is freely available)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CCCC](http://cccc.sourceforge.net/) (free, open source) which gives you lots of metrics about your program. Another option would be [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/) (not free).

This question may be a duplicate of this one: [Dead code detection in legacy C/C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229069/1158895)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the map file will be of any use.  If it's like other
map files I've seen, it won't indicate where (if anywhere) a symbol is
used—only where it is defined.  What you can do is run `dumpbin`
over your object files: `dumpbin /relocations`, for example, will in
fact display every use of a symbol with an address which may need
relocation (practically speaking, functions and variables with static
lifetime).  You then use your usual tools on the output to determine
whether the function you are interested in is there or not.  (As someone
who has worked mostly on Unix, I've installed CygWin and would use
`grep`.  I'm not familiar with the native equivalents to the different
Unix tools under Windows.)

It would be fairly simple (using Python, or some similar scripting
language) to write a small script which would parse the output of
`dumpbin /symbols` for each of your object files, to get the names of
all of the functions you've defined, then parses the output of `dumpbin
/relocations` to give you a list of the functions you use, and finally
does the diff of the two.  (Microsoft seems to have gone out of their
way to make the output of `dumpbin` difficult to use, but it's still not
that difficult; you just have to know which lines to ignore.)

Comment: Using compiler and linker options to create individual sections for each function and global variable and to throw away unused code would generate a map file with only the referenced symbols. You could then remove all non mentioned public functions and the static functions referred by them, which most compilers would complain about anyway.