# Finding dead code using Find All References

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, enums

I have a quite large C++ header file that requires cleanup. The file mainly contains enums and some defines. What I would like is to run "Find All References" (from within the VS right click context menu) on each define and enum element, and delete (or mark in some way) the lines where there are no more than 1 reference. Is there any tool that can help me automate this process?

The idea of using Find All References comes from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2380203/3790395

Comment: This kind of tool is called a static analysis tool and most can be configured to find unreachable or dead code.

Comment: this will potentially be non-helpful but... the feature you're describing is in Visual Studio 2013 (just get the express edition for your task and go on, i gues...)