# Best C++ static & run time tools

Tags: c++

Apologies if I missed this question already, but I searched and couldn't find it.

I have been out the C/C++ world for a little while and am back on a project.  I was wondering what tools are preferred today to help with development.

The types of tools I'm referring to are:

- Purify
- Electric Fence
- PC-Lint
- cscope

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you didn't find any answer because those are two completely different classes of tools?

Comment: @Neil, I do recognize that they are different types of tools, but often people have a standard set of tools in their toolbag when working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have mentioned some of the (mostly free) alternatives. This depends on the platform again.

Windows:

- VSTS 2008 is pretty good with its `/analyze` and profiling tools
- Rational Purify (as you've mentioned)
- BoundsChecker

Linux:

- Valgrind

Mac:

- Shark
- CHUD
- Sleuth
- MalloDebug

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could look at:

[What open source c++ static analysis tools are available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite impressed by [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/).  It's not perfect but it's the best static analysis tools I've worked with.

My favorite tool is still [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page) probably not the best static checker but has highlighted some basic errors that has been dormant in our code for years.

It is quick and easy to use.  It is free and open source.  It is actively developed so I expect to see it catch new error soon.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

- [Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/memory/index.html)
- [Performance Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/profiler/index.html)
- [Coverage Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/coverage/index.html)

Disclaimer: I am part of the team that makes those tools.

You've mentioned PC-Lint, you may want to try [Visual Lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint/index.html) by RiverBlade which puts a nice GUI onto the results and integrates with Visual Studio.