# C++ dynamic review tools

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, static-analysis

What's the best tool (commercial/open source) you've used for dynamic review/memory analysis of a C++ application?

EDIT: removed 'static' as there is already a [great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available) on this topic (thanks Iulian!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For dynamic memory analysis definitely [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: +1 Yes, I second that. Valgrind is a grand tool for memory analysis.

Comment: I see that there are no commercial options listed here...so I guess I'll accept this purely based on number of upvotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[CPPCheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page) has served me well for a while now. This is for statical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan, if you are on Windows and using MSVC++, then I can recommend BoundsChecker within DevPartner VC++ edition from Micro Focus. It has a feature within its memory tracking analysis called the Memory Resource Viewer. You use this to mark a point in time then look for allocations from that point forward. This plus the traditional heap corruption and other memory checks should help you dynamically track your C++ heap and stack issues. Shameless plug: I work on the DevPartner team. Look for DPS 10.5 with 64-bit support in BoundsChecker to launch February 4, 2011 at http://www.DevPartner.com.

Answer (score 0):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) on Linux

[Duma](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) on Windows

Answer (score 0):

For static code review KLOCWORKS is good.

For memory profiling, memory leaks identification, devpartner is a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft FxCop for static analysis (free). Parasoft Insure ($$$$) or IBM Purify ($$) for dynamic memory analysis.