# A C++ source code analyzer

Tags: c++, code-analysis

Could you suggest some open source tools that analyze C++ code and checks the following rules:

- naming conventions,
- file inclusions,
- function design,
- data types,
- flow control,
- memory allocation,
- file handling,
- portable code,
- runs under Solaris or SUSE

Comment: Please add some formatting to your question. Recommend a bulleted list for "naming conventions [...] portable code." For each bullet, please consider providing an example; something like "\n - **file inclusions**: verify that `#include`s occur alphabetically\n". This will help make it clearer what you're after. My guess is that there is no one tool that does all these things.

Comment: I've fixed as much as the formatting and stuff as I could to make this vaguely coherent, though it would be great if the OP would add some examples like @phooji mentioned.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?q=misra+checker

Of course, if the rules you're trying to enforce don't exactly match someone else's idea of a coding standard, no existing tool is going to work.

Comment: Thanks for that one. Unfortunately used up all my votes for the day ...

Answer (score 1):

It is still in early development (especially for C++) but its improving rapidly and is a really interesting open source project in a vibrant community. So see if the [CLang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have used coverity (http://coverity.com/)in my organization. It does static bug check analysis and I found it to be very useful. It is highly customization and provides a number of checks. I am not entirely sure if it works on solaris or not but I would recommend checking it out.

Comment: Not exactly open source ;) ... and quite expensive, too.