# How can I run GCC/Clang for static analysis? (warnings only)

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, clang, static-analysis

Without compiling code,  I would like GCC or Clang to report warnings.
Is it possible to run the compiler for static analysis only?
I can't find a way to pass the compiler warning flags and tell it not to compile.

edit:  just found that clang has a [static analyser](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Comment: Try `-fsyntax-only`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Move it to answer :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both GCC and Clang have an option `-fsyntax-only` that makes the compiler only perform syntax checking without any actual compilation.

Comment: However it's important to note that the flag is a lot more useful for clang, for G++ it doesn't do template instantiation, which means lots of possible diagnostics are missed

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other replies, `gcc` is doing some analysis during compilation (and even during some optimization passes). So you could discard the generated code and still get all the warnings with e.g. `gcc -Wall -O -c code.c -o /dev/null`

Notice that you could extend GCC with your additional passes doing some additional, application specific, checks and warnings, e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a high level domain specific language to extend GCC).

If you want strong static analysis and are willing to give additional annotations for that purpose consider also [Frama C](http://frama-c.com/).