# What are the go-to tools for finding errors in C code?

Tags: c, static-analysis, dynamic-analysis

It might be either static or dynamic analysis, preferably free.

Comment: I honestly like just using gcc's output.  I feel like it makes you learn more by not seeing code go wrong until you compile.  Plus, you can't beat the suspense!

Comment: I prefer the compiler. With extra warnings turned on, modern compilers are pretty good at finding problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available

Comment: @devnull C is not C++.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I know that but the link does mention tools like splint that are meant for C, in addition to describing compiler flags that might help.

Comment: @Joe: Windows or Linux.

Comment: Coccinelle helped me find many errors, even though it's very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) checks both C and C++ code and finds many errors.
- Valgrind is a tool for runtime analysis, but I mention it anyway. It is extremely useful for tracking memory errors like uninitialized usage or leaks.
- Also, activate ALL warnings your compiler has (GCC and clang: `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra`), which often reveals useful info.
- Note: clang sometimes generates much better warnings/errors than GCC
- To find logic errors, however, testing is required. Testing is required anyway, something that is not tested is per definition broken, as you cannot assume it works.
  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C) has a list of C unit testing software.

Comment: Isn't runtime analysis the same as dynamic analysis?

Comment: Just different wording.