# My own Smart pointer Implementation is creating issue with move operation

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, move-semantics, stdmove

In the below code, the output is turning out to be blank instead of constructor and destructor printouts. Without move operation, the code is working well. I am somehow messing up the move operation, please go through and give your inputs to guide further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class smart{
    public:
    smart():pt{nullptr}{
        
    }
    smart(T *ptr):pt{ptr}{
        
    } 
    
    T *pt;
    smart(const smart& ob)=delete;
    smart operator=(const smart& ob)=delete;

    smart (smart&& dyingob){
        this->pt=dyingob.pt;
        dyingob.pt=nullptr;
    }
    void operator=(smart&& dyingob){
        pt=dyingob.pt;
        dyingob.pt=nullptr;
    }
    T* operator ->(){return this->pt;};
    ~smart(){
        if(pt!=nullptr)
        delete pt;
    }
};
class A{
    public:
    A(int n){
        data=n;
        cout<<"\nconstructed";
    }
    ~A(){
        cout<<"\ndestructed";
    }
    int data;
};
int main()
{
    smart<A> ob(new A(5));
   smart<A> ob1;
   ob1=(std::move(ob));
    cout<<ob->data;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `#include <iostream>`

Comment: What are you expecting for `cout<<ob->data;` after `ob` has been moved?

Comment: Is `ob->data` supposed to be `ob1->data`? You're accessing `ob` after it's been gutted in `ob1=(std::move(ob));`.

Comment: got it thank you..when I am printing ob1->data it is working good.
but why the constructor call is not getting printed when I use ob->data, I don't understand as I am creating object before the print statement,

Comment: @TejRavi You can't expect anything from undefined behavior..

Comment: You did not miss `#include <iostream>`, you used the code formatter improperly.

Comment: `std::cout << ob->data` is probably crashing and exiting without flushing any buffers.  Try adding a `<< std::flush` to the end of your printing commands

Comment: @songyuanyao: Indeed, and - rather than ask us on SO, OP could have had that said to him by a static analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When noticing unexpected behavior, the first thing to check for is compiler warnings. But - without very specific flags perhaps - you are not likely to get those here.

However, a second thing to check for is what a [static analysis tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141498/what-open-source-c-static-analysis-tools-are-available) tells you about your program. Let's try [`clang-tidy`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) (version 14) for example:

```
1 warning generated.
/tmp/a.cpp:51:11: warning: Method called on moved-from object 'ob' [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.Move]
    cout<<ob->data;
          ^~~~
/tmp/a.cpp:50:4: note: Object 'ob' is moved
   ob1=(std::move(ob));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/a.cpp:51:11: note: Method called on moved-from object 'ob'
    cout<<ob->data;
          ^~~~
```

So, you're acting on a moved-from object (like commenters also told you... e.g. @songyuangyo). `ob->data` is a `nullptr` after the move, is it not?