# What's your favorite g++ option?

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

I am a newbie in C++ programming. 
When compiling I never use any option.

This is my day to day command:

```
g++ MyCode.cc -o MyCode
```

For safety practice what's the best option
to use?

Comment: Just a few results from the search:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/best-compiler-warning-level-for-c-c-compilers

Comment: You can achieve the same result by typing make

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
g++ -W -Wall -Werror
```

Will display all errors and warnings possible and treat them as errors.

Comment: To the OP - Do what this poster suggests!  You will save yourself many headaches if you just listen to the compiler warnings. Do not ignore them!

Comment: Actually, it doesn't enable all possible warnings. -Wwrite-strings and -Wconversion are good too.

Comment: Another good one is `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` although it can result in false positives if the dtor is protected.

Comment: Note: “`-W`” is the old name of `-Wextra`, and since it “adds” to `-Wall` I find the ordering “`-Wall -Wextra`” more logical.

Comment: All possible warnings? [Heh.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11714827/1858225) [Hehehehe.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/154630/1858225) [Hahahahaha!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5088460/1858225) [Bwahahahahaha!](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31573)

Answer (score 20):

“-Werror”: treats all warnings as errors so you have to fix them. Incredibly valuable.

Comment: Along with -Wall to turn on all the useful warnings, of course.

Answer (score 20):

```
g++ -g
```

I really need that debug information....

Answer (score 19):

If you thought you caught everything, try `-Wextra`

Answer (score 11):

```
g++ -Wall -Weffc++ -Werror -pedantic
```

When I'm using Boost, though, I drop it down to:

```
g++ -Wall -Werror
```

I'm anxiously awaiting GCC 4.4 and 4.5, though. There are some features coming that I really badly need.

Comment: What are the 4.4/4.5 features you're waiting for?

Comment: Lambdas (which I'm hoping show up in 4.5), auto variables (4.4), strongly-typed enums (4.4), and, most importantly, atomic<>, which I'm desperately hoping gets done in 4.5.

Comment: Unfortunately, -Weffc++ makes objects with internal pointers a nightmare.

Comment: I know. That's why I don't use it with Boost - just including a Boost header creates another 30-40 warnings.

Comment: there's `-isystem` for that @Tom

Answer (score 10):

```
-ansi
-pedantic

-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
-D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-D_GNU_SOURCE
-D_REENTRANT

-Wall
-Wextra
-Wwrite-strings
-Winit-self
-Wcast-align
-Wcast-qual
-Wold-style-cast
-Wpointer-arith
-Wstrict-aliasing
-Wformat=2
-Wuninitialized
-Wmissing-declarations
-Woverloaded-virtual
-Wnon-virtual-dtor
-Wctor-dtor-privacy
-Wno-long-long

-O3
-ftree-vectorize
-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2
-ffast-math
-fstrict-aliasing
-march=native/pentium4/nocona/core2
-msse2
-mfpmath=sse
```

Answer (score 8):

We always use

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it's a set: `-Wall -pedantic -std=c++98`

Answer (score 4):

-pipe, it speeds up compilation a little bit. Also -O2, which speeds up execution.

Comment: Optimization will generally interfere with debugging. For a newbie, using the -g and without -Ox would be preferable.

Comment: What speed improvements have you seen with -pipe?  I find it doesn't make a significant difference, as the bulk of the time is spent linking (which can't be parallelized across multiple cores, like compilation).

Answer (score 3):

I like `-march=athlon -O2 -pipe` for building most programs (I run Gentoo at home), and I use `-ansi -pedantic -Wall` for code I write myself.