# Flags to enable thorough and verbose g++ warnings

Tags: c++, g++, warnings

Often in C under `gcc`, I will start with the following set of warning flags (painfully assembled from multiple sources):

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wformat-nonliteral -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast \
-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Winline -Wundef \
-Wnested-externs -Wcast-qual -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter \
-Wfloat-equal -pedantic -ansi
```

I will build (at least my debug versions) with this set of warnings and fix everything I possibly can (usually everything), and then only remove flags if they are either not relevant or not fixable (almost never the case).  Sometimes, I'll also add `-Werror` if I have to step away while compiling.

I'm just picking up C++ (yes, I'm 15 years behind the times), and I'd like to start off on the right foot.

My question is: Does someone have a precompiled similar set of complete warning flags for C++ under `g++`?  (I know many of them will be the same.)

Comment: What gcc needs (since it's decided to blatantly _lie_ about `-Wall`) is a `-Wbloody_everything` flag :-)

Comment: You may mark your question as a dupe but you may also put your last edit as an answer since you actually answered your question. And I would be glad to upvote it then :)

Comment: Oh, good idea!  Can't accept for 2 days, but maybe someone else will come up with additional flags in the interim.

Comment: OP and @paxdiablo: GCC has [consistently rejected](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31573) this sort of thing, but it's available in Clang via `-Weverything`. I've read that even the Clang++ developers are a little concerned about users turning it on; apparently it was intended for internal development use only. This makes no sense, though, because turning on `-Weverything` is probably the best possible way to discover potentially helpful warnings that you didn't know about before.

Comment: OP and @paxdiablo There's now a way to figure out the complete list of warnings for a given GCC version: https://github.com/barro/compiler-warnings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn on (literally) ALL of GCC's warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

D'oh, all of my original searches turned up 99% of posts on how to *suppress* warnings (scarily enough), but I just ran across [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/best-compiler-warning-level-for-c-c-compilers/401276#401276), which has this lovely set of flags (some less relevant):

Cross checked with:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

```
-g -O -Wall -Weffc++ -pedantic  \
-pedantic-errors -Wextra -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align \
-Wcast-qual -Wconversion \
-Wdisabled-optimization \
-Werror -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 \
-Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security  \
-Wformat-y2k \
-Wimplicit  -Wimport  -Winit-self  -Winline \
-Winvalid-pch   \
-Wlong-long \
-Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-format-attribute   \
-Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn \
-Wpacked  -Wpadded -Wpointer-arith \
-Wredundant-decls \
-Wshadow -Wstack-protector \
-Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wswitch-default \
-Wswitch-enum \
-Wunreachable-code -Wunused \
-Wunused-parameter \
-Wvariadic-macros \
-Wwrite-strings
```

So, I think that's a good starting point.  Didn't realize this was a dupe, but at least it was deeply buried. :-)

Comment: Perhaps, but that seems to change between versions, and likely at the whim of sun spots and RMS, so being overly-explicit probably won't hurt.  It's a good starting point, anyway.

Comment: From a quick grep of 4.5.2's c-opts.c/opts.c for 'case OPT_W', you're missing: strict overflow, undef, strict nul sentinel, normalized, multichar, implicit function declaration, deprecated, endif labels, comment**s**, builtin macro redefined, larger than, larger than eq, abi.  It is crazy that there's not a command line option to list them.

Comment: I think it's crazier that `-Wall` doesn't do what one would expect it to.  But thank you, some of those look very useful!

Comment: Disabling warnings has its place. After all, they are "warnings". Another situation is when you enable a flag that enables multiple warnings, but you want to be selective about it.

Comment: @ereOn That's a very good idea, I cross checked with the documentation.

Comment: How are you able to use `-Waggregate-return`? This gives me a warning for every use of `begin/end()`

Answer (score 159):

I went through and found the minimal set of includes that should get the maximum level of warning. I then removed from that list the set of warnings that I feel do not actually indicate something bad is happening, or else have too many false positives to be used in a real build. I commented as to why each of the ones I excluded were excluded. This is my final set of suggested warnings:

`-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Werror -Wno-unused`

**Questionable warnings that are present:**

- I include `-Wno-unused` because I often have variables that I know I
  will use later, but do not yet have the functionality written for.
  Removing warnings about that allows me to write in my preferred style
  of occasionally deferring the implementation of things. It is useful
  to turn that off every once in a while to make sure nothing slipped
  through the cracks.
- `-Wdisabled-optimization` seems like a strong user-preference
  setting. I just added this one to my build (only for optimized builds
  for obvious reasons) and it didn't turn anything up, so it doesn't
  seem to be an especially chatty warning, at least for the way I code.
  I include it (even though code that triggers this warning isn't
  necessarily wrong) because I believe in working with my tools instead
  of against them. If gcc is telling me that it cannot optimize code
  for the way I wrote it, then I should look at rewriting it. I suspect
  that code that triggers this warning could benefit from being more
  modular, regardless, so although the code is not technically wrong
  (probably), stylistically it likely is.
- `-Wfloat-equal` warns for safe equality comparisons (in particular,
  comparison with a non-computed value of -1). An example in my code
  where I use this is that I have a vector of float. I go through this
  vector, and there are some elements I cannot evaluate yet what they
  should be, so I set them to -1.0f (since my problem only uses
  positive numbers, -1 is out of the domain). I later go through and
  update -1.0f values. It does not easily lend itself to a different
  method of operation. I suspect that most people don't have this
  problem, and comparison of an exact number in floating point is
  probably an error, so I'm including it in the default list.
- `-Wold-style-cast` has a lot of false positives in library code I'm using. In particular, the htonl family of functions used in networking, as well as a Rijndael (AES) encryption implementation I'm using has old-style casts that it warns me about. I intend to replace both of these, but I'm not sure if there is anything else in my code that it will complain about. Most users should probably have this on by default, though.
- `-Wsign-conversion` was a tough one (and almost didn't make the
  list). Turning it on in my code generated a huge amount of warnings
  (100+). Almost all of them were innocent. However, I have been
  careful to use signed integers wherever I wasn't sure, although for
  my particular problem domain, I would usually get a slight efficiency
  increase using unsigned values due to the large amount of integer
  division I do. I sacrificed this efficiency because I was concerned
  about accidentally promoting a signed integer to an unsigned and then
  dividing (which is not safe, unlike addition, subtraction, and
  multiplication). Turning on this warning allowed me to safely change
  most of my variables to unsigned types and add a few casts in some
  other places. It's currently a little hard to use because the warning
  isn't that smart. For instance, if you do `unsigned short + (integral
  constant expression)`, that result is implicitly promoted to int. It
  then warns about a potential sign problem if you assign that value to
  `unsigned` or `unsigned short`, even though it's safe. This is
  definitely the most optional warning for almost all users.
- `-Wsign-promo`: see `-Wsign-conversion`.
- `-Wswitch-default` seems pointless (you don't always want a default
  case if you've enumerated all possibilities explicitly). However,
  turning on this warning can enforce something that is probably a good
  idea. For cases where you explicitly want to ignore everything except
  the listed possibilities (but other numbers are possible), then put
  in `default: break;` to make it explicit. If you explicitly enumerate
  all possibilities, then turning on this warning will help ensure that
  you put something like assert (false) to make sure that you've
  actually covered all possible options. It lets you be explicit in
  what the domain of your problem is and programatically enforces that.
  However, you'll have to be careful in just sticking assert (false)
  everywhere. It's better than doing nothing with the default case, but
  as usual with assert, it won't work in release builds. In other
  words, you cannot rely on it to validate numbers that you get from,
  say, a network connection or a database that you do not have absolute
  control over. Exceptions or returning early are the best way to
  handle that (but still require you to have a default case!).
- `-Werror` is an important one for me. When compiling large amounts of
  code in a multi-threaded build with multiple targets, it's easy for a
  warning to slip by. Turning warnings into errors ensures that I
  notice them.

Then there is a set of warnings that are not included in the above list because I did not find them to be useful. These are the warnings and my comments on why I'm not including them in the default list:

**Warnings that are absent:**

- `-Wabi` is not needed because I'm not combining binaries from different compilers. I tried compiling with it anyway, and it didn't trigger, so it doesn't seem needlessly verbose.
- `-Waggregate-return` is not something that I consider an error. For
  instance, it triggers when using a range-based for loop on a vector
  of classes. Return value optimization should take care of any
  negative effects of this.
- `-Wconversion` triggers on this code: `short n = 0; n += 2;` The
  implicit conversion to int causes a warning when it's then converted
  back to its target type.
- `-Weffc++` includes a warning if all data members are not initialized
  in the initializer list. I intentionally do not do this in many
  cases, so the set of warnings is too cluttered to be useful. It's
  helpful to turn on every once in a while and scan for other warnings,
  though (such as non-virtual destructors of base classes). This would
  be more useful as a collection of warnings (like `-Wall`) instead of
  a single warning on its own.
- `-Winline` is absent because I don't use the inline keyword for
  optimization purposes, just to define functions inline in headers. I
  don't care if the optimizer actually inlines it. This warning also
  complains if it can't inline a function declared in a class body
  (such as an empty virtual destructor).
- `-Winvalid-pch` is missing because I don't use precompiled headers.
- `-Wmissing-format-attribute` is not used because I do not use gnu
  extensions. Same for `-Wsuggest-attribute` and several others
- Potentially notable for its absence is `-Wno-long-long`, which I have
  no need for. I compile with `-std=c++0x` (`-std=c++11` in GCC 4.7),
  which includes `long long` integer types. Those stuck back on C++98 /
  C++03 may consider adding that exclusion from the warning list.
- `-Wnormalized=nfc` is already the default option, and looks to be the
  best.
- `-Wpadded` is turned on occasionally to optimize the layout of
  classes, but it is not left on because not all classes have enough
  elements to remove padding at the end. In theory I could get some
  extra variables for 'free', but it's not worth the extra effort of
  maintaining that (if my class size changes, it's not easy to remove
  those previously free variables).
- `-Wstack-protector` is not used because I do not use `-fstack-protector`
- `-Wstrict-aliasing=3` is turned on by `-Wall` and is the most
  accurate, but it looks like level 1 and 2 give more warnings. In
  theory a lower level is a 'stronger' warning, but it's at the cost of
  more false positives. My own test code compiled cleanly under all 3
  levels.
- `-Wswitch-enum` isn't behavior that I want. I don't want to handle
  every switch statement explicitly. It would be useful if the language
  had some mechanism to activate this on specified switch statements
  (to ensure that future changes to the enum are handled everywhere
  that they need to be), but it's overkill for an "all-or-nothing"
  setting.
- `-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations` causes too many spurious warnings. It
  may be useful to apply this one periodically and manually verify the
  results. As an example, it generated this warning in my code when I
  looped over all elements in a vector to apply a set of functions to
  them (using the range-based for loop). It is also warning for the
  constructor of a const array of const std::string (where this is no
  loop in user code).
- `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant` and `-Wuseless-cast` are
  GCC-4.7-only warnings, which I will add when I transition to GCC 4.7.

I've filed a few bug reports / enhancement requests at gcc as a result of some of this research, so hopefully I'll be able to eventually add more of the warnings from the "do not include" list to the "include" list. This list includes all warnings mentioned in this thread (plus I think a few extra). Many of the warnings not explicitly mentioned in this post are included as part of another warning I do mention. If anyone notices any warnings that are excluded from this post entirely, let me know.

**edit:** It looks like I had missed several (which I have now added in). There is actually a second page at http://gcc.gnu.org that is quite well hidden. [General warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) and [C++ options (scroll down to the bottom for warnings)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options)

Comment: I recently submitted an enhancement request based on my research for this answer: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53313. It would dramatically simplify the warning situation by creating warning levels. In my proposal, my suggested set of warnings is approximately -W4, with an additional proposal to create -Winf, which would mean -Weverything-and-I-really-mean-it-this-time

Comment: Enhancement request that would cause part of -Wpadded be added to the recommended list: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53514

Comment: Enhancement request that would cause parts of -Weffc++ to be added to the recommended list: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16166

Comment: I don't really understand your argumentation about `-Wswitch-enum` isn't just writing perhaps doing nothing `default:` branch technically disables warning from specific switch?

Comment: @Predelnik: It's trickier than that. `-Wswitch-enum` warns if you do not explicitly handle every enumeration value in a switch, and `default` does not count as explicit. On the other hand, `-Wswitch-default` warns you if your switch does not have a `default` case, even if you have explicitly covered all possible values.

Comment: This list is awesome. FYI, someone has now written an automated tool to find all warnings for a given version of GCC or Clang, and has published these lists for many compiler versions; see here: https://github.com/barro/compiler-warnings

Comment: I suggest to add -Wnon-virtual-dtor, which nowadays is activated with -Weffc++ but comes without the potential issues of -Weffc++ .

Comment: BTW - use `-isystem` instead of `-I` on your "old library code" to prevent all those false positives

Comment: -Wfloat-equal isn't actually in your list in this answer.

Comment: `-Wstrict-overflow=5` is acutally VERY questionable. Even the manual mentions that this generates lots of false positives.

Comment: Flamefire, you are correct. I have found that values greater than `-Wstrict-overflow=2` tend to be too noisy to be useful.

Comment: Please delete `-Werror` - at least from the upper command-line. It might be advisable to use it, but - it doesn't add warnings, and that's what OP had asked about.

Answer (score 17):

Some of those are already included in `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

A good base setup for C is:

`-std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Werror`

and for C++

`-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++`

(skipping `-Werror` for C++ since `-Weffc++` has some annoyances)

Comment: -Werror can be disabled for specific types of warnings, for example: -Werror -Weffc++ -Wno-error=effc++

Comment: [ansi](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options): In C mode, this is equivalent to `-std=c89`. In C++ mode, it is equivalent to `-std=c++98`. i.e. if youre specifying some other `std`, dont use `ansi`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
export CFLAGS="`gcc --help=warnings | grep '\-W' | awk '{print $1 \" \"}' |
sort | uniq` -pedantic -fdiagnostics-show-option -Werror"
```

That's a quick and dirty start which will definitely need some tuning; for one thing, even if you call the compiler by the appropriate name for your language (e.g. `g++` for C++), you will get warnings that don't apply to that language (and the compiler will throw up its hands and refuse to continue until you remove the warning).

Another thing is that I added in `-Werror`, because if you aren't fixing the warnings, why do you care about turning them on? You can also take warnings out of the list. (For example, I almost never use `-Waggregate-return` with C++.)

Some warnings won't do anything without other performance related options (`-Wstack-protector`). `-fdiagnostics-show-option` and the GCC manual are your friends.

By the way, some warnings are mutually exclusive; in particular using `-Wtraditional` and `-Wold-style-definition` along with `-Werror`, will not compile.