# GCC: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type -- in Template Parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, comparison, range

I want to write a template that returns me the smallest signed integer type that can represent a given number. This is my solution:

```
/**
 * Helper for IntTypeThatFits.
 * Template parameters indicate whether the given number fits into 8, 16 or 32
 * bits. If neither of them is true, it is assumed that it fits 64 bits.
 */
template <bool fits8, bool fits16, bool fits32>
struct IntTypeThatFitsHelper { };

// specializations for picking the right type
// these are all valid combinations of the flags
template<> struct IntTypeThatFitsHelper<true, true, true> { typedef int8_t Result; };
template<> struct IntTypeThatFitsHelper<false, true, true> { typedef int16_t Result; };
template<> struct IntTypeThatFitsHelper<false, false, true> { typedef int32_t Result; };
template<> struct IntTypeThatFitsHelper<false, false, false> { typedef int64_t Result; };

/// Finds the smallest integer type that can represent the given number.
template <int64_t n>
struct IntTypeThatFits
{
    typedef typename IntTypeThatFitsHelper<
        (n <= numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()) && (n >= numeric_limits<int8_t>::min()), 
        (n <= numeric_limits<int16_t>::max()) && (n >= numeric_limits<int16_t>::min()), 
        (n <= numeric_limits<int32_t>::max()) && (n >= numeric_limits<int32_t>::min())
    >::Result Result;
};
```

However, GCC does not accept this code. I get an error "comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]". Why does that happen? n is a signed 64bit integer, and all of the comparisons may be true or false for different values of n, or am I overlooking something?

I will be glad for any help.

Edit: I should mention that I am using C++11.

Comment: How could something be _not_ less than `max` _and_ not more than `min`? Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It is checking whether the `n` is within the ranges for **different** data types.

Comment: For those who want to try their hand at it, I managed to get a version on [ideone](http://ideone.com/PhAJN) (which does not support `constexpr` yet...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue with gcc, warnings in templated code can be frustrating. You can either change the warning or use another approach.

As you may know, templated code is analyzed twice:

- once when first encountered (parsing)
- once when instantiated for a given type/value

The problem here is that at instantiation, the check is trivial (yes `65` fits into an `int` thank you), and the compiler fails to realize that this warning does not hold for all instantiations :( It is very frustrating indeed for those of us who strive to have a warning-free compiling experience with warnings *on*.

You have 3 possibilities:

- deactivate this warning, or demote it to a non-error
- use a pragma to selectively deactivate it for this code
- rework the code in another format so that it does not trigger the warning any longer

Note that sometimes the 3rd possibility involves a massive change and much more complicated solution. I advise against complicated one's code *just* to get rid of clueless warnings.

**EDIT**:

One possible workaround:

```
template <int64_t n>
struct IntTypeThatFits {
    static int64_t const max8 = std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max();
    static int64_t const min8 = std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min();

    static int64_t const max16 = std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::max();
    static int64_t const min16 = std::numeric_limits<int16_t>::min();

    static int64_t const max32 = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::max();
    static int64_t const min32 = std::numeric_limits<int32_t>::min();

    typedef typename IntTypeThatFitsHelper<
        (n <= max8 ) && (n >= min8 ), 
        (n <= max16) && (n >= min16), 
        (n <= max32) && (n >= min32)
    >::Result Result;
};
```

... by changing the type of the data used in the comparison, it should silence the compiler warning. I suppose explicit casting (`int64_t(std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max())`) could work too, but I found this more readable.

Comment: So this is a bug in GCC? After all, the warning only makes sense for runtime comparisons.

Comment: @BenjaminSchug: I would not qualify it as a *bug* because you could argue it works as expected. After all in some cases you could **want** to be warned at instantiation time :x It is just that in your case it's harmful...

Comment: In this context, the comparison is _required_ to be a compile-time constant, otherwise I could not use it as a template argument. So if this is really the reason for the warning, how is that not a bug?

Comment: @BenjaminSchug: I posted a work-around to the issue you experimented. The idea is to use the value provided by `numeric_limit<X>::min` et al. but in a type that is more palatable for gcc's analyses.

Comment: @BenjaminSchug: In this precise context I agree it could probably be removed, but it's a bug only if the specs say it should behave otherwise ;) That being said, since gcc is open to discussion, you could perhaps signal it on their mailing list, they might be interested in this issue.

Comment: @BenjaminSchug I would consider this a bug in gcc, as the warning is clearly bogus. You get similar bogus warnings for shifts > size of operand in templated code, and they are considered bugs too. You should open a bug report for it.

Comment: This is a bug. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434640/gcc-comparison-is-always-true-due-to-limited-range-of-data-type-in-template/10435458#10435458

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Your workaround works. :-)
For the current situation, I will still stick to Boost, but in the general case, this is useful to know.

Comment: +1 for "I advise against complicated changes just to get rid of clueless warnings" As the OP is using C++11 anyway, you could use `constexpr` instead of `const`

Answer (score 5):

The error is happening because you asked GCC to give you errors about this warning with `-Werror=type-limits`.  The warning `-Wtype-limits` gives you a warning if you ever do a comparison which will always be true due to the ranges of the given data types, for example:

```
uint8_t x;
if(x >= 0) { ... }  // always true, unsigned integers are non-negative
if(x >= 256) { ... }  // always false

int32_t x;
if(x < 9223372036854775808LL) { ... }  // always true
```

This warning can sometimes be useful, but in many cases including this it's just useless pedantry and can be ignored.  It's normally a warning (enabled as part of `-Wextra`, if you use that), but with `-Werror` or `-Werror=type-limits`, GCC makes it an error.

Since in this case it's not actually indicative of a potential problem with your code, just turn off the warning with `-Wno-type-limits`, or make it not be an error with `Werror=no-type-limits` if you don't mind seeing those warnings in the compiler output.

Comment: Where in the OP's code is there a comparison that is always true due to the range of data types?

Comment: I don't want to disable that warning completely because it is useful in the normal case. Here it should just not trigger because that comparison is _supposed_ and _required_ to be a compile time constant.

Comment: I've had several cases of endless loops caused by the loop counter variable being too small for the end value. `-Wtype-limits` detects these cases but I had turned it off because of the annoying redundant warnings. Now I have it enabled and just put up with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
   typedef typename IntTypeThatFitsHelper<
        (n <= numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()) && (n >= numeric_limits<int8_t>::min()), 
        (n <= numeric_limits<int16_t>::max()) && (n >= numeric_limits<int16_t>::min()), 
        (n <= numeric_limits<int32_t>::max()) && (n >= numeric_limits<int32_t>::min())
    >::Result Result;
```

You can't do that in C++ (in C++11 you can) - `numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()` is not compile time constant.  Are you using C++11?

BTW, Boost provides this for you already:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html

Comment: Yes, I am using C++11. Should have mentioned that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with Boost, that seems to work. I really should always check Boost before writing something myself. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers of what the problem is are wrong. I don't believe this is a case of an over-eager compiler, but I believe it's a compiler bug. This code still fires the warning:

```
template<int64_t n>
bool a() {
    return (n <= static_cast<int64_t>(std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()));
}
```

When calling `a<500>();`, but this code does not:

```
template<int64_t n>
bool a() {
    return (n <= static_cast<int64_t>(127));
}
```

std::numeric_limits::max() evaluates to 127. I'll file a bugzilla report for this later today if no one else does.

Comment: You could consider an over-eager compiler an buggy compiler :-)

Comment: I just sent a bug report to their mailing list: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2012-05/msg00311.html

Comment: @BenjaminSchug Better use the bugzilla next time http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ . Anything reported there gets send to the mailing list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning because for some instantations of `template <int64_t n>
struct IntTypeThatFits` with small `n` (smaller than 2^32) some of the comparisons are always true (sic!) because of the range of the operand *during compile time* .

This could be considered a bogus warning in this case, because your code relies on it, OTOH you explictly requested to make it an error with a `-Werror` or similar command line switch, you basically get what you asked here.

Comment: *you basically get what you asked here* -> I disagree. It is a useful warning in many situations, and there are plenty of instantiations of the template where it will not fire. I wish compilers would avoid such warnings when they do not hold for every instantiations... though I do recognize it's complicated to evaluate.

Comment: IMHO generally using `-Werror` is just asking for trouble. Warnings are a good thing, but there are to many bogus warnings in gcc out there to make them erroes all the time. Especially with templated code evaluated during compile time.

Comment: I have no problems with `-Werror` in my code, and this is what my warning list looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088460/flags-to-enable-thorough-and-verbose-g-warnings/9862800#9862800 (I occasionally turn on those other warnings I mention but say I don't use).

Comment: @drhirsch: [Broken Window Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) => as soon as you let warnings escape in the build, they propagate, until the few useful warnings (`-Wreturn` !!) are lost in the noise. I prefer to have a narrow, carefully selected list of warnings, and have them into errors, rather than heaps of useless warnings sprouted to the screen or no warning at all.

Comment: @DavidStone This is probably tightly related to coding style. For me, `-Wunused` is always on, defining a variable for later use is and not using it is a big no :-) OTOH `-pedantic` just wont work for me.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I fix _all_ my warnings, but I prefer to not let the compiler error out on a warning but instead let it finish the build.

Comment: I absolutely need -Werror because otherwise, the warnings get lost in a sea of `g++ -o build/debug/main.o -c -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -Wtons-of-other-warning-flags -g -pedantic src/main.cpp` `g++ -o build/optimized/main.o -c -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -Wtons-of-other-warning-flags -Ofast -march=native -funsafe-loop-optimizations -flto=4 -Wdisabled-optimization -DNDEBUG src/main.cpp` etc.

Comment: @drhirsch: I've got too much output with my build, if I let it finish I don't have enough history available in my shell to spot the warnings ;)

Comment: Hmm, my IDE (eclipse) filters that for me and marks the lines with warnings and errors

Comment: @drhirsch: In my group, we have agreed that you should always fix any warnings before committing. The -Werror flag is a handy way of enforcing that agreement. Especially because this means that builds with warnings will show up as failures in the build server. ;-)