# Can I ignore the gcc warning: ‘Foo::m_bar’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, compilation, warnings

```
struct Bar
{
    Bar() {}
};


struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;
    Bar m_bar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

When using C++11 `default` keyword and gcc warning `-Weffc++`, gcc outputs:

> warning: ‘Foo::m_bar’ should be initialized in the member
>   initialization list [-Weffc++]

Is it safe to ignore this warning? Should I file a bug to gcc?

Comment: "Should I file a bug to gcc" - no. When you think it's a compiler bug, then it isn't.

Comment: I don't see the warnings if I do `Bar() = default`.

Comment: Pity there's no downvoting comments...

Comment: Unfortunately, `-Weffc++` is not really useful currently. It is one of the only warnings that didn't make it onto my huge list of warnings that I use on every project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088460/flags-to-enable-thorough-and-verbose-g-warnings/9862800#9862800

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can ignore or suppress the warning. This is a misinterpretation of one of the Effective C++ guidelines. The guideline says to prefer initialisation to assignment, but in your example, `m_bar` will be initialised. Your code is correct.

Source: [Jonathan Wakely](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16166#c3) in GCC's bug tracker:

> # Item 12: Prefer initialization to assignment in constructors.
>
> Replaced by Item 4: "Make sure that objects are initialized before they're
>   used", and G++ misinterprets the original item anyway and warns about *any*
>   member without a mem-initializer, which is very annoying: there's no point
>   initializing a std::string, it has a perfectly safe default constructor.  My
>   -Wmeminit patch for PR 2972 should replace the current warning for this item,
>   as it only warns about members left uninitialized by the constructor.

(And as it's a known issue, there's no need to report it as a bug again.)

Comment: @MatthieuM Except for false negatives!

Answer (score 7):

Is it alright to ignore this warning? Yes.

Is it a good idea to ignore this warning? Depends(*)

Should you file a bug to gcc? No(*)

(*)

- `default` constructor in fact initialises `m_bar` just fine, you can test that
- it a bit weird that g++ doesn't get that
- you selected very verbose warning setting
- warning is not about correctness of your code, rather about style
- you can't correct this and keep default constructor for Foo and custom constructor for Bar

`man g++`, section -Weffc++

> Warn about violations of the following style guidelines from Scott Meyers’ Effective C++ book:
>
> - Item 11: Define a copy constructor and an assignment operator for classes with dynamically allocated memory.
> - Item 12: Prefer initialization to assignment in constructors.
> - Item 14: Make destructors virtual in base classes.
> - Item 15: Have "operator=" return a reference to *this.
> - Item 23: Don’t try to return a reference when you must return an object.
>
> Also warn about violations of the following style guidelines from Scott Meyers’ More Effective C++ book:
>
> - Item 6: Distinguish between prefix and postfix forms of increment and decrement operators.
> - Item 7: Never overload "&&", "││", or ",".
>
> When selecting this option, be aware that the standard library headers do not obey all of these guidelines.