# What are a recommended set of compiler flags to help reduce errors

Tags: c++, compiler-flags

I am a computer science masters student (Conversion) who has recently been taught C, and is now moving on to learning Java. Alongside Java, I have taken it upon myself to learn C++ as it is going to be necessary for the project I wish to do.

While we were learning C, we were required to ensure that our code always compiled with the following flags

```
-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -ansi -O2
```

I learned that using these flags helps you pick up some cases of poor practise and also subtle bugs which might not appear straight away (and some that do) and so makes you a lot more productive.

I was wondering if anybody can recommend for me a general set of flags I should always use when compiling C++ programs? I've only just done the classic 'hello world' program at the time of writing so not much room for bugs. But I'd like to start with good habits...

Comment: this question could be answered by reading `man gcc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flags to enable thorough and verbose g++ warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088460/flags-to-enable-thorough-and-verbose-g-warnings)

Answer (score 3):

I will definitely include initially `-Werror` which will convert all warnings to `error`.

Comment: Ok. Are the above flags applicable to C++ as well?

Comment: Yes, I wonder why both `pedantic` and `ansi`. Any difference?

Comment: The combination of the two is explained [here](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Tips/tips_on_gcc.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Clang, `-Weverything` which enables *literally* all warnings, unlike `-Wall`.

Then you can explicitly disable (`-Wno-...`) those that you think are too much. I have usually only about 5 or 10 of them.