# How to deal with third party headers that don't pass compiler flags

Tags: c++, opencv, warnings

For a project at university, I need to work with OpenCV. In order to do that I am learning c++ (also because I wanted to anyway). Having learned C last term, we were provided with a set of flags to increase the strictness and verbosity of the compiler. Having done some searching on what flags we can use with g++ in order to make the compiler as strict as possible, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088460/flags-to-enable-thorough-and-verbose-g-warnings) question. What I have found though is that in order to get even an empty `main()` to compile with the OpenCV headers without warnings I need to switch off a number of the flags including `-Wall` and `-Wextra` which were actually *required* on my course for C programs.

Is there any way of using the OpenCV headers but only applying the warning headers to the code that *I* write?

Comment: In GCC, you can use `-i` instead of `-I` to include headers as "system headers", and GCC won't produce warnings for those.

Comment: I am using pkg-config in my makefile though. Is there a way of getting it to output the lowercase option?

Comment: Don't know, read the manual for pkg-config. `--variable=includedir` seems to give you the necessary ingredient.

Comment: Ok thanks. I used SED to swap the upper with lowercase, but now it can't find the header at all haha...

Comment: @BenWainwright, Where can we find som doc reference of `-i`, I was trying to get some info on it. Interesting flag

Comment: Just realised that my question is basically a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers. I changed -i to -isystem and it did the trick :)

Comment: Oh, right, it's `-isystem`, not `-i`. Sorry.