# Why does the C++ modulo operator return 0 for -1 % str.size()?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, modulus, modulo

I'm confused why the following code produces this output:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = -1;
    string s = "abc";
    int j = s.size();
    int x = 1 % 3;
    int y = i % j; 
    int z = i % s.size(); 
    cout << s.size() << endl; // 3
    cout << x << endl;        // 1
    cout << y << endl;        // -1
    cout << z << endl;        // 0
}
```

Why is z = 0? Does it have to do with casting?

Comment: Without testing, I bet this is related to signed-ness.

Comment: Pro tip: see what `static_cast<size_t>(-1)` is. Then calculate its remainder when divided by 3. Spoiler alert: it's 0.

Comment: It's not a modulus operator. It is a remainder operator.

Comment: Yes is casting, s.size() is unsigned, -1 transformed to unsigned is 2^32-1, which is divisible by 3

Comment: Exactly what @EduardoPascualAseff said. Whats happening here is datatype overflow. -1 does not exist as an unsigned integer. So it overflows to (max unsigned int - 1).

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff -- it's not **casting**, it's **converting**. There are no casts in the code in the question. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, stripping down your code to a *minimal* example, you're asking why this prints `0`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a = -1;
    std::string::size_type b = 3; 
    int c = a % b;
    std::cout << c << '\n';
}
```

The primary operation in question here is this:

```
a % b
```

Per the standard,

**5.6 Multiplicative operators [expr.mul]**

> 2. The operands of * and / shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration
>      type; the operands of % shall have integral or unscoped enumeration
>      type. *The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands
>      and determine the type of the result*.

So.. what about those "usual arithmetic conversions"? This is to mate the types of the two operands to a common type *prior* to performing the actual operation. The following are considered *in order* :

- If both operands are integers, integer promotion is first performed on both operands. If after integer promotion the operands still have different types, conversion continues as follows:

  - If one operand has an unsigned type T whose conversion rank is at least as high as that of the other operand’s type, then the other operand is converted to type T.
  - Otherwise, one operand has a signed type T whose conversion rank is higher than that of the other operand’s type. The other operand is converted to type T only if type T is capable of representing all values of its previous type.
  - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned type that corresponds to the signed type T.

That's a *lot* of legalize for what effectively says this:

- You have two operands, a `signed int` and a `std::string::size_type`
- The rank of `std::string::size_type` is *greater* than that of `signed int`
- Therefore, the `signed int` operand is converted to type `std::string:size_type` *prior* to the operation being requested.

So all that is left is the conversion, to wit, there is one more piece of legalize:

**4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral]**

> 2. If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>      where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).
>      [Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is
>      conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no
>      truncation). —end note]

That means, on a 32-bit `std::string::size_type` platform, you're going to get 2<sup>32</sup>-1 as the converted value from `int` (-1).

Which means...

```
4294967295 % 3
```

Which is... *zero*. If `std::string::size_type` is 64-bits, then everything above stays the same, save for the final calculation, which would be:

```
18446744073709551615 % 3
```

Answer (score 3):

What really happens here:

```
int z = i % s.size();
```

is `i` is converted to `size_t` because the other side `s.size()` is `size_t`. And unlike `int`, `size_t` is unsigned; That is to say the value is interpreted as a positive number.

Check the output of this line:

```
std::cout << (size_t)-1 << std::endl;
```

to see what -1 has become.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I will edit my answer. The point is: the sign change is causing the behavior here.

Comment: @JaMiT And `size_t` is unsigned. I don't see anything wrong here except that '`unsigned`' should just be 'unsigned'

Comment: @user207421 That would be a correction. There is also the cast in the code, though.

Answer (score 1):

@GhaziMajdoub's answer is correct, but - why don't you let the compiler tell you what's happening?

Let's use the [Flags to enable thorough and verbose g++ warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088460/flags-to-enable-thorough-and-verbose-g-warnings) ...

```
$ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy \ 
-Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations \
-Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual \
-Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel \
-Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Werror -Wno-unused -o a a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:12:13: error: conversion to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ {aka
‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result
[-Werror=sign-conversion]
   12 |     int z = i % s.size();
      |             ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:12:13: warning: conversion to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ 
{aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-
conversion]
   12 |     int z = i % s.size();
      |             ^
```

and there you have it: `i` is converted to `long unsigned int`, so it's no longer `-1`.