# i was trying to execute a simple c++ program in vs code but this gives me a lot of errors. also the colour of the "cout" keyword is not changing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[image: error]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout <<"sup";
    return 0;
}
```

I have been using turbo c + + till now  and I have done everything in my knowledge but it is not helping. I use mingw compiler

Comment: Unrelated, but you may want to read [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/11082165).

Comment: You're compiling using `gcc` (the C compiler). You want to use `g++` (the C++ compiler).

Comment: I have tried the g++ and  all the errors are gone  but still  no output    cout keyword is in white colour (should be in blue  i think)

Comment: `std::cout` is just a global (namespace level) variable. It's not a keyword.

Comment: @Amal `g++ test.cpp` only compiles the code and generates `a.out` executable run that executable. Since you're using windows I guess you'd get `a.exe`.

Comment: yeah its done THANK YOU,  but  why is it   "a.exe" why not test.exe   thanks

Comment: @Amal That's just the default name GCC picks if you don't specify one yourself. You can specify an output name with the `-o` flag, e.g. `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe`.

Comment: Also, if you're just getting started with C++, it's highly recommended that you [enable compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5088460/11082165). For manually compilation, a good basic set of warning flags is `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion`.