# Better compiler warnings?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to add additional warning flags to g++ so that it will warn me about the unitialized b variable in the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a, b;
  cin >> a;
  while (a>0) b++;
  cout << a;
}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I have tried turning on the flags listed at this other question:
[Flags to enable thorough and verbose g++ warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088460/flags-to-enable-thorough-and-verbose-g-warnings) but nothing triggered. ("Tickled!" as I have learned below.)

Comment: Did you try with `g++ -Wall -Wextra` ?

Comment: My tests show no warnings from GCC with hefty warning groups (-Wall, -Wextra, -pedantic), and Clang giving a warning.

Comment: You can add compilation flag ie. -Wall. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings

Comment: What optimization level?

Comment: google: GCC warnings

Comment: Note that it *may* be [Bug 18501](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18501) in gcc.  It has been open for a little while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option you are after is likely `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` or `-Wuninitialized`.  Both of these are part of the `-Wall` option which turns on these, and many other warnings (the `-Wxxx` options are related to warnings).

Full documentation of the warning options for gcc may be read at: [Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) in the gcc documentation.

You may also find that `-Wextra` may be of use to you (either alone, or in conjunction with `-Wall`).  `-Wextra` also enables `-Wuninitialized`, but it has other items that are not always set by `-Wall` and are ones that I like to see (things like `-Wunused-parameter` and `-Wunused-but-set-parameter`)... though thats not specific to this bit of code.

---

That said... (yea, there's a "that said")... I can't seem to tickle an error with this functionality with gcc that is is available on http://gcc.godbolt.org.

Extending your code with some that is specifically described in the documentation for `-Wmaybe-uninitialized`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a, b;
  int x, y, z;
  // warning: variable ‘y’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  cin >> a;
  while (a>0) b++;
  switch(a) {
    case 1: x = 1; y = 1; z++; break;
    // warning: ‘z’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    case 2: x = 4; y = 2; break;
    case 3: x = 5; y = 3;
  }
  cout << a;
  cout << b;
  cout << x;
}
```

This is an attempt to tickle a number of the unused and unitized warnings.  I was able to get the `z` variable to produce the error, but for some reason `b++` in that while loop does not generate an error or warning with gcc (tested using gcc 4.9.0).

> [image: Warnings with gcc 4.9.0]

clang version 3.4.1, however, does produce warnings with these command line options for both `b` and `z`

> [image: Warnings with clang 3.4.1]

And while `-Wall` and `-Wextra` *should* produce the warnings you are after, for some reason they do not produce the desired warnings for this specific piece of code in gcc 4.9.0

Comment: @chris `#clang++ -std=c++1y` ... its not gcc.

Comment: `#` is a comment. Look two lines below. It's just easy to keep a few things I use often and switch between them without having to form them again.

Comment: Hmm... that is indeed the case.  http://gcc.godbolt.org (another nice online compiler) can show other various errors, but this one is slipping through.

Comment: @chris so, you are indeed correct.  I stills stand by my answer that for the general case, those options *should* produce the desired warnings and certain other bits of code do generate the error.  This specific SSCCE that daveagp provides doesn't appear to tickle those warnings though with gcc (though I can make *other* bits of code that are similar in nature do it). I would be quite happy to find out what isn't working right (is it a misunderstanding of the standard on my part? a bug in gcc?).

Comment: Oh, of course. I was surprised to find no warnings, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!!! You must use -Wuninitialized.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings