# Force function to be called only with specific types

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I was looking at [enforcing type safety when casting char* to bool in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714895/enforcing-type-safety-when-casting-char-to-bool-in-c11) and it was suggested that if you do

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) = delete;

void foo(int f) {}
```

That `foo` will only work when given a explicit `int` argument.  I made a test case:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T) = delete;

void foo(int f) {}

int main()
{
    foo(1);
    foo(3.0);
    foo(short(5));
    foo(float(7.0));
    foo(long(9));
}
```

I used coliru to compile the code with `g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f8de2e0746289f8)) and I got the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:12: error: use of deleted function 'void foo(T) [with T = double]'
     foo(3.0);
            ^
main.cpp:2:6: note: declared here
 void foo(T) = delete;
      ^
main.cpp:10:17: error: use of deleted function 'void foo(T) [with T = short int]'
     foo(short(5));
                 ^
main.cpp:2:6: note: declared here
 void foo(T) = delete;
      ^
main.cpp:11:19: error: use of deleted function 'void foo(T) [with T = float]'
     foo(float(7.0));
                   ^
main.cpp:2:6: note: declared here
 void foo(T) = delete;
      ^
main.cpp:12:16: error: use of deleted function 'void foo(T) [with T = long int]'
     foo(long(9));
                ^
main.cpp:2:6: note: declared here
 void foo(T) = delete;
      ^
```

<sup>compiling with clang also produced similar errors</sup>

Now when I was reading about `= delete` on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) it stated

> If the function is overloaded, overload resolution takes place first, and the program is only ill-formed if the deleted function was selected.

So if cppreference is correct and my program is ill-formed does this just mean it will not compile or is it unspecified or undefined behavior?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The result is exactly as the quote says it should be.

Comment: what was your expectation of the behavior? It seems like it failed for 4 of the 5 cases, with only one of those cases representing the `int` value that was supposed to work. That's what I'd think would happen.

Comment: Ill formed, but **with** diagnostic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed. First, for each invocation of `foo`, we perform overload resolution. That will call:

```
foo(1);            // foo(int )
foo(3.0);          // foo<T>, T=double
foo(short(5));     // foo<T>, T=short
foo(float(7.0));   // foo<T>, T=float
foo(long(9));      // foo<T>, T=long
```

Four of those functions are explicitly `deleted` and, from [dcl.fct.def.delete]:

> A program that refers to a deleted function implicitly or explicitly, other than to declare it, is ill-formed.

It's not undefined or unspecified behavior. It should simply not compile.