# Definition of function specialization errors when following =delete declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I have a general template function that is `=delete`d, and a specialization for `int`

```
template <typename> void f() = delete;

template <>
void f<int>() { }
```

My goal is to have a function template that errors at **compile**-time (not link-time) when a specialization is not provided for the template arguments.  `f<int>()` should succeed and `f<double>()` should error. While the above works with gcc, it fails with clang with `error: redefinition of 'f'`.  If I remove the `=delete` it compiles fine, but then `f<double>()` doesn't fail until link time.

Is the above valid? Is the specialization of a deleted template a redefinition or should the specialization be another candidate for overload resolution.

Comment: This might just be a clang bug. Although when reading through N3936 looking for relevant text I was surprised to find "When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation". Looks like that text made it into C++14 too

Comment: instead of specializing can you overload it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716589/force-function-to-be-called-only-with-specific-types)?

Comment: @NathanOliver I would if I could. The template type isn't related to any of the arguments.

Comment: In this code sample the specialization should have `inline` if the function body is present (otherwise it may lead to ODR violation)

Comment: @M.M right, but the error from that is: `error: inline declaration of 'f<int>' follows non-inline definition` which is less helpful in determining what's being confused here.

Comment: That message doesn't make any sense, which leads me to believe clang is bugged in the case of specializing a deleted function

Comment: [Here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17537) is the 2 year old bug report. The proposed "solution" at the end is particularly neat.