# How do I write a matrix? it prints random numbers

Tags: c, math

I'm trying write a code that matrix 3*3 but it doesn't work correctly. it prints random numbers. what I did wrong?

```
    int matrix[3][3];   
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
        scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
      }
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
        printf("%d ",&matrix[i][j]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/2d-arrays-in-c-example/

Comment: Compiler warnings are your friend.

Comment: thanks for your help. but compiler didn't show this error

Comment: It's not printing random numbers; it is printing the address of of each element (`&matrix[i][j]`)

Comment: If you'd turned on compiler warnings, like using `Wall` with `gcc`, you would have seen this: `matrix_print.c:19:16: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
       printf("%d ",&matrix[i][j]);
               ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               %n
`

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Stackoverflow is not a *fix-my-bugs* site

Comment: @AkınTokluoglu it shows **warnings** and not errors. [How to turn on (literally) ALL of GCC's warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714827/995714)

Comment: You are right. I'm new to this. I will pay attention to them from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `&` while printing values
Use below code for printing.

```
 printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
```

Comment: @AkınTokluoglu Next time, enable all warnings when compiling your code (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)