# Is there a gcc warning flag for when short-circuit evaluation may result in a function not being called?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

For example, in the code:

```
bool foo = bar || baz();
```

the function `baz()` may not be called. I've found that this is a common source of bugs for me and I'm wondering if there's a way for GCC to print a warning.

Comment: in some sense this is like asking to get a warning for `if (condition) foo();` because `foo` might not be called. I would not expect a warning for that

Comment: Such warning would give you *a lot* of false positives on stuff like `if (ptr && ptr->foo())`...

Comment: You might take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings and try to compile a simple test case with all possible warnings enabled.  If you still don't get a warning, then you know the answer is "no, there is no such flag".

Comment: I don't get a warning with `-Wall -W -Wextra`.  Nor with clang 9.0.0 and `-Weverything`, see https://godbolt.org/z/QbKdA6.  This strongly suggests there is no such flag.

Comment: This would be something for `lint`-like or code quality tools.

Comment: Changing the order to `bool foo = baz() || bar;` gurarantees `baz()` is always called. If you already know this, then I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: @Ripi2: I think the question is how to have the compiler warn when you write `foo = bar || baz()`, on the grounds that you might really have meant `foo = baz() || bar`.

Comment: Of course it may not be called. It would be very strange for issuing a warning for that. If you need warnings for stuff like that, avoid those constructs and write `foo = bar; if(!bar) foo = baz();` instead.

Comment: well, write `bool foo = bar | baz()` with a single `|` (bitwise or is not shortcutting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a warning flag for this, it would generate a warning for too many common conditions (`if(condition) bar();`, `if(foo && foo->bar) baz();`, etc).

Instead, do something similar to this:

```
bool foo = baz() || bar;
```

or this:

```
bool foo = bar | baz();
```

These unconditionally call `baz()`.