# What is the use of -Wall command while compiling C code

Tags: c, compilation

I know that we use -g flag for storing the output to debug a C code, but what is the use of -Wall when compiling it?

Comment: Easy: Not making stupid mistakes because the compiler will warn you (`-W`) about `all` potential problems. Not literally all, but the most important ones anyway.

Comment: Also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings

Answer (score 1):

It enables most of the compiler's warning messages. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html.

Comment: Not all of them.

Comment: OP probably ignores them (if he asked this question). So for him it probably does nothing.