# Make someone give me some pointers on how to make this code work

Tags: c, cs50

I have some errors in my code, that I don't know to solve, I think I'm calling the function to main wrong but my program stops in the <sum = sum side(a)> I can't solve on my own, I tried everything, so I'm coming here to see if someone can give me some advice or pointers on how to solve it

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//is the size of the array 
const int n = 3;

int sum_side(float x[]);

int main(void)
{
    float sum;
    int a[n];

    sum = sum_side(a);
    // is used to get 3 sides from the user all have to be positive
    do
    {
        a[0] = get_int("First side: ");
        a[1] = get_int("Second side: ");
        a[2] = get_int("Third side: ");

    }
    while(a[0] <= 0 || a[1] <= 0 || a[2] <=0);
    
    //is used to say if it can be a triangle or nor
    if(sum_side(a[n]) == 1)
    {
        printf("Can be a triangle? ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can't be a triangle? ");
    }
}


int sum_side(float x[])
{
    // Check that sum of any two sides greater than third
    if ((x[0] + x[1] <= x[2]) || (x[1] + x[2] <= x[0]) || (x[2] + x[0] <= x[1]))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // if we passe the test, we're good!
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Given `const int n = 3;` and the array `int a[n];`, the value `a[n]` is outside the bounds of the array.  And given `int sum_side(float x[]);`, you're passing a invalid `int` *value* to a function that expects a `float` array - those aren't the same thing at all.

Comment: To simplify what @AndrewHenle is saying `float_side(a[n])`  should be `float_side(a)`

Comment: @Barmar Except that `a` is defined as `int a[n]`, not `float a[n];`...

Comment: `sum = sum_side(a);` doesn't make much sense when the array is uninitialized before you've taken the input.

Comment: I think your triangle check is wrong. You need to find the longest side, then check the sum of the other two sides is greater.

Comment: @SimonGoater, the length of *each* side of a triangle must be strictly shorter than the sum of the other two side lengths.  It is sufficient to check just the longest side, as you suggest, but the OP is not wrong to check all the sides.  And it's not clear to me that your way would be any more efficient.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Re: "the length of each side of a triangle must be strictly shorter than the sum of the other two side lengths." --> If we dis-allow zero area triangles as valid, your idea seems reasonable.  Yet unless we account for higher precision needs, the _sum_, although greater than the 3rd with real math, may be the same with `float` math due to rounding. So I suggest the `==` case return valid.

Comment: @SimonGoater Better to subtract the 2nd longest from the longest and then compare that difference to the 3rd longest.  That way we do not lose important precision.

Answer (score 1):

> if someone can give me some advice or pointers on how to solve it

#1  **Enable all compiler warnings**.  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11714827/2410359)

If OP learns anything from this post it is to use local tools, like many compiler warnings, to increase productivity and reduce debug time.

---

Sample warnings with OP's code:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'sum_side' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   14 |     sum = sum_side(a);
      |                    ^
      |                    |
      |                    int *
note: expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'int *'
    7 | int sum_side(float x[]);
      |              ~~~~~~^~~


warning: conversion from 'int' to 'float' may change value [-Wconversion]
   14 |     sum = sum_side(a);
      |           ^~~~~~~~
warning: passing argument 1 of 'sum_side' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   26 |     if(sum_side(a[n]) == 1)
      |                 ~^~~
      |                  |
      |                  int
note: expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'int'
    7 | int sum_side(float x[]);
      |              ~~~~~~^~~
warning: variable 'sum' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   11 |     float sum;
      |           ^~~
```

---

#2 **We are using *floating point* (FP), not infinite precision math.**

FP addition may incur round-off error.  Edge cases are tricky.

Code like `x[0] + x[1] < x[2]` versus `x[0] + x[1] <= x[2]` favors allowing extreme edge cases to pass.  Consider sizes: (1.0e30f, 1.0e30f, 1.0), OP's code would fail that when it should pass.

IMO, even sides of (0,0,0) is a valid triangle.

In this `float` case, we could use `double` to handle precision and range issues.

```
bool sum_side_alt(const float x[]) {
  // Check that sum of any two sides greater than (or the same as) the third.
  return ((0.0 + x[0] + x[1] >= x[2]) &&
      (0.0 + x[1] + x[2] >= x[0]) &&
      (0.0 + x[2] + x[0] >= x[1]));
  //   ^---------------^ addition uses double math 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is just for the pedantic who want to avoid rounding issues**

`x[0] + x[1]`, in general, incurs rounding and may overflow to infinity that affects the correctness of the compare.  To avoid these issues, let us try a new approach, *without* using wider types:

```
//  Return true if valid values for a triangle.
bool triangle_test(float x[]) {
  // Find the greatest
  if (x[0] > x[1]) {
    swap(&x[0], &x[1]);
  }
  if (x[1] > x[2]) {
    swap(&x[1], &x[2]);
  }
  // x[2] now has the greatest.
 
  if (x[0] > x[1]) {
    swap(&x[0], &x[1]);
  }
  // x[0] now has the least.

  // Optional test
  if (x[0] <= 0.0) {
    return false; // OP seems to want to exclude these.
  }

  /*
  If x[1] is at least x[2]/2, then x[2] - x[1] will form an _exact_ difference without overflow.
  Comparing the difference with x[2] will be exact.

  If x[1] is smaller than 0.5*x[2], then x[2] - x[1] will at least x[2]/2,
  even if rounded and larger than x[0] in all cases. 
  */
  float diff = x[2] - x[1];
  return diff < x[0];
}
```