# What are the useful GCC flags for C?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

Beyond setting [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall), and setting [`-std=XXX`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-1), what other really useful, but less known compiler flags are there for use in C?

I'm particularly interested in any additional warnings, and/or and turning warnings into errors in some cases to absolutely minimize any accidental type mismatches.

Comment: Well `-save-temps`, `-Wshadow` and `-fmudflap` were the greatest finds I didn't know of, thanks to all.

Comment: Context, as far as I can tell: running `gcc -c [flags-go-here] -o myprog.o myprog.c` to compile (not link) a C program.

Comment: Related: *[Recommended GCC warning options for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c)*

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Several of the `-f` code generation options are interesting:

- [`-fverbose-asm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fverbose-asm) is useful if you're compiling with `-S` to examine the assembly output - it adds some informative comments.
- [`-finstrument-functions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-finstrument-functions) adds code to call user-supplied profiling functions at every function entry and exit point.
- [`--coverage`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-coverage) instruments the branches and calls in the program and creates a coverage notes file, so that when the program is run coverage data is produced that can be formatted by the [`gcov`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html#Gcov) program to help analysing test coverage.
- [`-fsanitize={address`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003daddress)`,`[`thread`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003dthread)`,`[`undefined`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003dthread)`}` enables the AddressSanitizer, ThreadSanitizer and UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer code sanitizers, respectively.  These instrument the program to check for various sorts of errors at runtime.

Previously this answer also mentioned [`-ftrapv`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-ftrapv), however this functionality has been superseded by `-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow` which is one of the sanitizers enabled by [`-fsanitize=undefined`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003dundefined).

Comment: For `-ftrapv`, do have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851061/how-to-make-gcc-ftrapv-work .. seems like there's a bug long waiting to get fixed.

Comment: Can You Check The Above Comment?

Comment: -ftrapv was essentially superseded by -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow.

Answer (score 159):

Here are mine:

- [`-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) and [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall): essential.
- [`-Wfloat-equal`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wfloat-equal): useful because usually testing floating-point numbers for equality is bad.
- [`-Wundef`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wundef): warn if an uninitialized identifier is evaluated in an `#if` directive.
- [`-Wshadow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wshadow): warn whenever a local variable shadows another local variable, parameter or global variable or whenever a built-in function is shadowed.
- [`-Wpointer-arith`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wpointer-arith): warn if anything depends upon the size of a function or of `void`.
- [`-Wcast-align`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wcast-align): warn whenever a pointer is cast such that the required alignment of the target is increased.  For example, warn if a `char *` is cast to an `int *` on machines where integers can only be accessed at two- or four-byte boundaries.
- [`-Wstrict-prototypes`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wstrict-prototypes): warn if a function is declared or defined without specifying the argument types.
- [`-Wstrict-overflow=5`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wstrict-overflow): warns about cases where the compiler optimizes based on the assumption that signed overflow does not occur.  (The value 5 may be too strict, see the manual page.)
- [`-Wwrite-strings`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wwrite-strings): give string constants the type `const char[`*length*`]` so that copying the address of one into a non-`const char *` pointer will get a warning.
- [`-Waggregate-return`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Waggregate-return): warn if any functions that return structures or unions are defined or called.
- [`-Wcast-qual`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wcast-qual): warn whenever a pointer is cast to remove a type qualifier from the target type<sup>*</sup>.
- [`-Wswitch-default`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wswitch-default): warn whenever a `switch` statement does not have a `default` case<sup>*</sup>.
- [`-Wswitch-enum`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wswitch-enum): warn whenever a `switch` statement has an index of enumerated type and lacks a `case` for one or more of the named codes of that enumeration<sup>*</sup>.
- [`-Wconversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wconversion): warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value<sup>*</sup>.
- [`-Wunreachable-code`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunreachable_002dcode-437): warn if the compiler detects that code will never be executed<sup>*</sup>.

Those marked <sup>*</sup> sometimes give too many spurious warnings, so I use them on as-needed basis.

Comment: Pretty complete list, just want to add one more; `-Wformat=2`: Extra format checks on printf/scanf functions.

Comment: arent all these implied by `-Wall`?

Comment: @chacham15, no, I don't think so.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @Alok hmm, maybe its not standard among distributions? I know that on my mbp I have to explicitly turn off `-Wwrite-strings` because I hate it so much.

Comment: @chacham15, maybe.  But the description for `-Wwrite-strings` specifically says it's not a part of `-Wall`: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wwrite_002dstrings-415.  Maybe something else in your setup is setting that flag?  Or maybe you're compiling C++?

Comment: `-Wunreachable-code`'s functionality has been removed (however gcc won't warn if the option is still being used...) https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00360.html

Answer (score 56):

Always use `-O` or above (`-O1`, `-O2`, `-Os`, etc.). At the default optimization level, gcc goes for compilation speed and doesn't do enough analysis to warn about things like unitialized variables.

Consider making `-Werror` policy, as warnings that don't stop the compilation tend to be ignored.

`-Wall` pretty much turns on the warnings that are very likely to be errors.

Warnings included in `-Wextra` tend to flag common, legitimate code. They may be useful for code reviews (though lint-style programs find a lot more pitfalls are more flexible), but I wouldn't turn them on for normal development.

`-Wfloat-equal` is a good idea if the developers on the project are unfamiliar with floating point, and a bad idea if they are.

`-Winit-self` is useful; I wonder why it's not included in `-Wuninitialized`.

`-Wpointer-arith` is useful if you have mostly-portable code that doesn't work with `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 41):

The most useful flag, as far as I'm concerned, is [-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) which puts debugging information into the executable such that you can debug it and step through the source (unless you're proficient and reading assembly and like the `stepi` command) of a program while it's executing.

Answer (score 41):

`-save-temps`

This leaves behind the results of the preprocessor and the assembly.

The preprocessed source is useful for debugging macros.

The assembly is useful for determining what optimizations went into effect. For instance, you may want to verify that GCC is doing tail call optimization on some recursive functions, as without it you can potentially overflow the stack.

Comment: I did wonder how you got it to do that... I've always just asked gcc to dump the assembly if I needed it.

Answer (score 36):

[-fmudflap](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fmudflap-765)—adds runtime checks to all risky pointer operations to catch [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This effectively immunizes your program again buffer overflows and helps to catch all kinds of dangling pointers.

See *[Mudflap Pointer Debugging](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging)*

Here's a demo:

#### FIle *mf.c*

```
int main()
{
  int a[10];
  a[10] = 1; // <-- Oh noes, line 4
}
```

#### Compilation and execution

```
gcc -fmudflap mf.c -lmudflap
./a.out
```

Output:

```
*******
mudflap violation 1 (check/write): time=1280862302.170759 ptr=0x7fff96eb3d00 size=44
pc=0x7f3a575503c1 location=`mf.c:4:2 (main)'
      /usr/lib/libmudflap.so.0(__mf_check+0x41) [0x7f3a575503c1]
      ./a.out(main+0x90) [0x400a54]
      /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f3a571e2c4d]
Nearby object 1: checked region begins 0B into and ends 4B after
mudflap object 0xf9c560: name=`mf.c:3:6 (main) a'
bounds=[0x7fff96eb3d00,0x7fff96eb3d27] size=40 area=stack check=0r/3w liveness=3
alloc time=1280862302.170749 pc=0x7f3a57550cb1
number of nearby objects: 1
```

Comment: Hmmm, mudflap seems pretty nasty :P

Comment: `-fmudflap` is no longer supported since GCC 4.9, you get `warning: switch '-fmudflap' is no longer supported`. It was superseded by AddressSanitizer.

Comment: Yep, the last version with it included [was 4.8.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fmudflap-765) (released 2015-06-23). GCC 4.9.0  was released 2014-04-22 (note overlapping dates).

Answer (score 27):

It is not really related to C/C++, but it is useful anyway:

```
@file
```

Put all the good flags in previous answers (which you all have specified) in a 'file', and use this above flag to use all the flags in that file together.

for example:

File : compilerFlags

> -Wall
>
> -std=c99
>
> -Wextra

Then compile:

```
gcc yourSourceFile @compilerFlags
```

Answer (score 17):

[-march=native](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/LoongArch-Options.html#index--march) to produce optimized code for the platform (=chip) on which you are compiling.

Comment: If you are compiling for non-native machines where you don't know the target, you can use mtune=xxx which optimizes without using instruction sets. For example mtune=generic is kept up to date with the "average" case processors.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to know the preprocessor flags that are predefined by the compiler:

`echo | gcc -E -dM -`

Answer (score 15):

It's not really helpful for detecting errors, but the rarely mentioned [-masm=intel](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-masm_003ddialect) option makes using `-S` to inspect the assembly output much, much nicer.

AT&T assembly syntax hurts my head far too much.

Comment: The difference between AT&T and Intel to me is the difference between C# and Java. Just syntax. Both awful. :)

Comment: +1 @michael for making gcc use intel syntax instead of the god awful at&t. Inspecting assembly uses enough brain cycles -- no need to waste brain cycles that src goes before dest in opcodes. Now if only gcc supports the __asm {} inline like other compilers we're all set!

Answer (score 11):

Here's a great flag that hasn't been mentioned:

```
-Werror-implicit-function-declaration
```

Give a error whenever a function is used before being declared.

Comment: [Since GCC 4.6](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings/blob/master/gcc/warnings-gcc-4.6.txt) (released 2011-03-25), this has been `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` instead (or an alias?). *[-Wimplicit-function-declaration](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wimplicit-function-declaration)*

Answer (score 10):

My makefile typically contains

`CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -Os -ggdb` 
`...` 
`g++ $(CFLAGS) -o junk $<` 
`gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<` 
`rm -f junk`

The most important of these options have been discussed before, so I'll point out the two features that have not been pointed out yet:

Even though I'm working on a codebase that *needs* to be plain C for portability to some platform that *still* has no decent C++ compiler, I do an "extra" compile with the C++ compiler (in addition to the C compiler). That has 3 benefits:

1. the C++ compiler occasionally gives me better warning messages than the C compiler.
2. The C++ compiler accepts the [-Weffc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Weffc_002b_002b) option, which occasionally gives me some useful tips, which I would miss out on if I only compiled it in plain C.
3. I can keep the code relatively easy to port to C++, avoiding a few boundary conditions where plain C code is invalid C++ code (such as defining a variable named "bool").

Yes, I'm a hopelessly optimistic Pollyanna that keeps thinking that *surely* any month now that one platform will either be declared obsolete, or gain a decent C++ compiler, and we can finally switch to C++. In my mind, it is inevitable—the only question is whether that happens before or after management finally issues everyone a pony. :-)

Comment: A good point with writing it as C++, I consider this often. (subset naturally)

Comment: I should point out that C being deprecated in favor of C++ will never happen, sorry :)

Comment: consider -o /dev/null instead of rm -f junk

Answer (score 9):

`-Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes`

Comment: And `-Wold-style-definition` if you have to deal with recidivists who think K&R style functions are a good idea, even with prototyped declarations.  (I have to deal with people like that.  It really annoys me when I find new code written in K&R.  It is bad enough having legacy K&R stuff that isn't fixed, but new code!  Grump!!!)

Comment: *[-Wold-style-definition](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wold-style-definition)*

Answer (score 8):

```
man gcc
```

The manual is full of interesting flags with good descriptions. However, -Wall will probably make GCC as verbose as possible. If you want more interesting data, you should take a look at [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) or some other tool for checking for errors.

Comment: It is loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong, though. `man gcc | nl` reports over 11000 lines. That's more than the infamous `bash` manpage!

Comment: Thank god they crammed it into a man page, instead of one of those godawful unnavigateable "info" pages.

Answer (score 7):

There is [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror), which treats all warnings as errors and stops the compilation. The [`gcc` manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) explains every command line switch for your compiler.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Since you didn't mention which machine architecture you are using, the `gcc` flags might be different between yours and whatever link anybody might suggest. This is why manual pages are supplied with your software.

Answer (score 6):

Well, [-Wextra](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) should be standard, too. [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) turns warnings into errors (which can be *very* annoying, especially if you compile without [-Wno-unused-result](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-unused-result)). [-pedantic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) in combination with [std=c89](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20std=) gives you additional warnings if you use [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) features.

But that's about it. You cannot tune a C compiler into something more type-safe than C itself.

Answer (score 6):

`-M*` family of options.

These let you write make files that automatically figure out what header files your C or C++ source files should depend on. GCC will generate make files with this dependency information, and then you -include them from your primary make file.

Here's an example of an extremely generic makefile using [-MD](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-MD) and [-MP](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-MP) that will compile a directory full of C++ source and header files, and figure out all the dependencies automatically:

```
CPPFLAGS += -MD -MP
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)

my_executable: $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)
        g++ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

-include $(SRC:%.cpp=%.d)
```

Here's a blog post that discusses it in more depth: *[Automatically generate makefile dependencies](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/automatically_generate_makefile_dependencies.html)*

Answer (score 5):

I found this question looking for a flag to fix a specific issue. I don't see it on here, so I'll add one that was just stumping me on [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068619/inverted-arguments-in-scanf/13068825#13068825):

The [-Wformat=2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat) flag

> `-Wformat` => Check calls to `printf` and `scanf`, etc., to make sure that the arguments supplied have types appropriate to the format string specified...

And the really important part about it ([according to the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat-207)):

> `-Wformat` is included in `-Wall`. For more control over some aspects of format checking, the options `-Wformat-y2k`, `-Wno-format-extra-args`, `-Wno-format-zero-length`, `-Wformat-nonliteral`, `-Wformat-security`, and `-Wformat=2` are available, but are not included in -Wall.`

So, just because you have [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) doesn't mean you have it all. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes use [-s](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-s) for a much smaller executable:

```
-s
    Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.
```

Source: *[Options for Linking](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)*

Comment: you should just run `strip` on your binary, this way you can have a binary with debug information, remove it later for distribution.

Comment: Yes, `strip` works too but `-s` can be quicker and easier, though it's not as elaborate as running `strip`

Answer (score 4):

[-Wfloat-equal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wfloat-equal)

From *[char * const argv[]](http://mces.blogspot.com/2005/07/char-const-argv.html)*:

> One of the other new warnings that I like is the -Wfloat-equal. That one warns whenever you [have] a floating-point number in an equality condition. That's briliant! [sic] If you have every [sic] programmed a computer graphics or (worse:) computational geometry algorithm, you know that no two floats ever match with equality...

Comment: My floats *do* match with equality, as I know what I'm doing.

Comment: @RolandIllig I don't (*sobs uncontrollably while adding 0.1 and 0.2 over and over again on a piece of paper*).

Answer (score 3):

While this answer may be slightly off-topic and the question is a worthy +1 from me, since

> I'm particularly interested in any additional warnings, and/or and turning warnings into errors in some cases to absolutely minimize any accidental type mismatches.

there is a tool that should catch out ***all*** errors and potential errors that may not be obvious. There's [Splint](http://www.splint.org/) which, IMHO, does a way better job in catching out errors compared to GCC or any other compiler for that matter. That is a worthy tool to have in your tool chest.

Static checking via a lint-type of tool such as Splint, should have been part of a compiler toolchain.

Comment: It always shows an error cannot file preprocessor file in C:\include , i am not sure what to do

Answer (score 2):

> I'm particularly interested in any additional warnings,

In addition to [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall), the [-W](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) or [-Wextra](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) option (`-W` works with older versions of gcc as well as newer ones; more recent versions support the alternative name `-Wextra`, which means the same thing, but is more descriptive) enables various additional warnings.

There are also even more warnings which are not enabled by either of those, generally for things that are more questionably bad.  The set of available options is dependent on which gcc version you are using - consult `man gcc` or `info gcc` for details, or see the [online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for the particular gcc version you're interested in.  And [-pedantic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-1) issues all warnings required by the particular standard being used (which depends on other options such as [-std=xxx](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-1) or [-ansi](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-ANSI-support)) and complains about use of gcc extensions.

> and/or and turning warnings into errors in some cases to absolutely minimize any accidental type
> mismatches.

`-Werror` turns all warnings into errors.  I don't think gcc lets you do that selectively for particular warnings, though.

You'll probably find that you have to be selective about which warnings are enabled on a per-project basis (especially if you use `-Werror`), as header files from external libraries can trip some of them.  (`-pedantic` in particular tends to be unhelpful in this respect, in my experience.)

Comment: "I don't think gcc lets you do that selectively for particular warnings, though."  Actually, you can with `-Werror=some-warning`.

Answer (score 1):

- [-Wmissing-prototypes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-prototypes): If a global function is defined without a previous prototype declaration.
- [-Wformat-security](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat-security): Warns about uses of format functions that represent possible security problems. At present, this warns about calls to `printf` and `scanf` functions where the format string is not a string literal and there are no format arguments

Answer (score 1):

- [-Werror=](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)[return-type](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wreturn-type): Enforce an error when a function doesn't have any return in GCC. It is `/we4716` in Visual Studio.
- [-Werror=](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)[implicit-function-declaration](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wimplicit-function-declaration): Enforce an error when a function is used without being defined / not included. It is `/we4013` in [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).
- [-Werror=](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror)[incompatible-pointer-types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wincompatible-pointer-types): Enforce an error when a pointer's type mismatched with the expected pointer type. It is `/we4133` in Visual Studio.

Actually, I'd like to keep my C code cross-platform. I use [CMake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMake), and I put the provided cflags into [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) like:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Windows")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /we4013 /we4133 /we4716")
elseif (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux" OR CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Darwin")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=return-type")
endif()
```