# ld: unrecognized option '--push-state--no-as-needed'

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-14.04, linker-errors, ld

My build fails with the following linker error message:

> FAILED: : && /usr/bin/g++  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -fsanitize=undefined,address -Wno-unused-parameter  -fsanitize=undefined,address  -rdynamic *.o  -o SCE  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qt59/lib /opt/qt59/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.9.1 /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a -lpthread -lutil -lgrpc++ /opt/qt59/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.9.1 /opt/qt59/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.9.1 && :
>   /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: unrecognized option '--push-state--no-as-needed'

You can see [the full build log here](https://travis-ci.org/Toeger/SCE/builds/371071764). The error is in line 2211 and versions are printed in lines 2104ff.

Which tool causes the error?

- Is `gcc 7.3.0` using an incorrect linker flag? The [`ld` documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) indicates that `--push-state` and `--no-as-needed` are separate commands.
- Is `ld 2.28` too old to understand the linker flag? The [change log](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=ld/NEWS;hb=refs/tags/binutils-2_30) doesn't list anything that seems related.
- The command `&& /usr/bin/g++` looks odd, it should be `/usr/bin/g++`. Using `make` instead of `ninja` shows the same linking error.

It builds correctly on Debian testing which is using `gcc 7.3.0` as well and `ld 2.30`, but there doesn't seem to be a working `binutils-2.30` ppa for Ubuntu Trusty.

How do I successfully build my project on Travis?

Comment: I can confirm this with Gcc7 on Ubuntu 16.04 using CMake (make and ninja). Gcc6 and Clang 4-6 work fine; Gcc7 also works fine locally (Arch).

Comment: Turning of the undefined-behavior sanitizer seems to "solve" the problem. Most likely a bug in g++.

Comment: Probably this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-7/7.3.0-16ubuntu2

Comment: Oddly, I'm having the problem with GCC 5, 6 and 7. No such problem on Debian Stretch with hand-rolled 7.3.0. Turning off the sanitizer also fixes it for me, thanks. I notified Travis support about 14h ago and will update them.

Comment: The simple fix is to use gold linker by passing `-fuse-ld=gold` option to gcc

Comment: @makerj That actually works. Consider making that an answer.

Comment: If you're only using `-fsanitize=undefined`, another workaround that seems to help: you don't need to link against the sanitizer if you tell the compiler to trap at run time: `-fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error`.

Answer (score 11):

GCC 7 is *fixed* with [**7.3.0-16ubuntu3**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-7/7.3.0-16ubuntu3) (tested on *Ubuntu 18.04*). This version is available though the [Ubuntu Toolchain Test PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) (for 16.04.1 and 14.04).

Tested with Make only, but it should work with Ninja too. Both Sanitizer, ASan and UBsan, enabled.

There's not much related to this problem in the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-7/7.3.0-16ubuntu3) though:

> gcc-7 (7.3.0-16ubuntu3) bionic; urgency=medium
>
> - Update to SVN 20180415 (r259389) from the gcc-7-branch.
>
>   - Fix PR libstdc++/85222.
> - Remove our own PR libstdc++/85222 backport.

---

#### Update:

**GCC 7 (*7.3.0-16ubuntu3*)** is ***still broken*** on **Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier**.

What you can do to workaround this:

#### A. Update to Ubuntu 18.04

The problem is fixed on ***Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS)***'s Gcc7.

---

#### B. Dockerize and update to Ubuntu 18.04

If an update is not possible, eg. running on a CI system, it's still an option to use ***Docker*** and an up-to-date Ubuntu.

---

#### C. Disable UB Sanitizer

The Problem occurs only when using GCC7 with UB Sanitizer enabled. As [*tobias-brüll*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171688/tobias-br%C3%BCll) noted in the comments: ***Turning*** the ***UB Sanitizer off*** prevents the error.

---

#### D. Use Gold Linker

Another workaround posted by [*makerj*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050087/makerj): Using the ***Gold Linker*** doesn't cause the problem.

Eg. on *CMake* pass it through the [**`CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-fuse-ld=gold ..
```

Comment: What is going wrong [here](https://travis-ci.org/Toeger/SCE/jobs/379386713#L487)? It looks like it is using the ppa you linked, yet the error persists.

Comment: Seems it's fixed only on Ubuntu 18.04. That's really bad. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If option D (from [ollo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622894/ollo)'s answer) is not working for you try next commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/binutils --yes
sudo apt-get update -qq --yes
sudo apt-get install -qq --yes --force-yes binutils
```

This is from: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/scripts/travis/before_install.x86_64-asan.sh

And the issue was discribed here: https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/3216