# Satisfying -Wreturn-type in a function that can't return

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, warnings, return-type

I'm in a situation like this (this example is a bit weird but it's representative of what I've got here):

```
struct complicated;

struct somestruct {
  template <int N> complicated& function ();
};

struct complicated {
private:
  friend complicated & somestruct::function<1> ();
  complicated () { }
};

template <int N> inline complicated& somestruct::function () {
  static_assert(N == 1, "invalid N");
} // <--- warning: no return statement

template <> inline complicated& somestruct::function<1> () {
  static complicated just_an_example;
  return just_an_example;
}

int main () {
  //somestruct().function<0>();  // correctly fails to compile
  somestruct().function<1>();
}
```

Where:

- The program is designed to fail at compile time if `somestruct::function<int N>` is generated for any value of `N` other than 1.
- The type `complicated` is not constructible at all if `N` is something besides 1 (not for the artificial `friend`-based reason in this example, but same idea).
- `somestruct::function<int N>` is specialized for `N == 1`.

And therefore:

- The non-specialized `somestruct::function` will not execute, because either the non-specialized code is not generated, or the `static_assert` prevents compilation.

However:

- The non-specialized case is declared as returning a `complicated&`, but...
- A non-temporary `complicated` cannot be constructed in that context, and so...
- I've got nothing to return (and null references [can't officially exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364536/is-null-reference-possible)).

But since I have nothing to return there, it generates a `return-type` warning (no return in function returning non-void).

For various reasons, I'd like to kill the warning, but disabling the warning for the entire unit (`-Wno-return-type`) is not an option in this context. Also I cannot introduce any non-`std` dependencies.

So my question is: **Is there either a) something I can return that has no side-effects or b) some way to mark that the code can't reach that point, so that the compiler is satisfied that a return statement isn't needed in the non-specialized case?**

This is with both GCC 5.x and GCC 9.x, with `--std=c++17`. I'm OK with something GCC-specific. I'm also OK if GCC 5.x is not satisfied although I'd prefer both to work.

---

Note: The solution (given in [the dupe link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381544/how-to-hint-to-gcc-that-a-line-should-be-unreachable-at-compile-time) and suggested in the comments below), in case anybody finds this but can't put it together, is:

```
template <int N> inline complicated& somestruct::function () {
  static_assert(N == 1, "invalid N");
  __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

That is, GCC's `__builtin_unreachable()` after the `static_assert` in the non-specialized function. At least on GCC 5 and 9, it kills the warning but the program still behaves, compiles, and fails to compile (in the non-specialized case) as intended.

Another solution from the comments below is the `[[noreturn]]` attribute:

```
template <int N> [[noreturn]] inline complicated& somestruct::function () {
  static_assert(N == 1, "invalid N");
}
```

Which might be better since it's standard (since C++11), although it does generate an extraneous "noreturn function does return" warning when the `static_assert` fails.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381544/how-to-hint-to-gcc-that-a-line-should-be-unreachable-at-compile-time) help?

Comment: @PaulSanders That kind of looks like the opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: @PaulSanders NICE. Nailed it. I'm going to go ahead and close this as a dupe. Thank you. I hoped and suspected it'd be that straightforward.

Comment: @cigien Nope, that's exactly it. In this case, `__builtin_unreachable()` right after the `static_assert` kills the warning and the program still behaves, compiles, and fails to compile (if non specialized version is used) correctly.

Comment: Oh, I see. I misread the question then. Sorry about that.

Comment: It looks like marking the method `[[noreturn]]` works too, and IMO that's better than `__builtin_unreachable()` since `[[noreturn]]` is standard.

Comment: @HTNW Oh neat. Just tried it; can confirm it also works. The only quirk is that when the non-specialized version is used and the `static_assert` fails, it generates a "noreturn function does return" warning. Inconsequential, since the compilation intentionally fails anyways; but it's there.