# How to solve default garbage values in C?

Tags: c, programming-languages, default-value, compile-time, garbage

If we declare a variable in the C programming as integer without defining value then printf prints some garbage value from buffer. Is there any method to prevent printing the garbage value?

I want to check if something can be done at compile time? if possible?

Answer (score 12):

Yes. Initialise the variable.

Comment: I would only use intilization be compiler option (to different values, e.g. 0, 1, 0xFF) this for testing purposes.

Comment: @mielacademy: always pass at least `-O -Wall` to gcc, then it will warn about common mistakes such as uninitialized variables. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375697/useful-gcc-flags-for-c

Comment: You shouldnt use compiler options to work around a bug in your coed. And make no mistake, using an uninitialised variable *is* a bug.

Comment: Damn typo. Incidentally, I once had a bug in my coed, but some penicillin sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says the following:

> In computing, an uninitialized variable is a variable that is
>   declared but is  not set to a definite
>   known value before it is used. It will
>   have some value,  but not a
>   predictable one. As such it is a
>   programming error and a common source 
>   of bugs in software

So initialize it to a default value.

Answer (score 1):

**At compile times, most compilers such as the GNU compiler can identify where an uninitialized variables is used. However, you may need to set flags, such as `-Wall` for the GNU compiler.**

The value of the variable is *already* here though it could be any value. Namely it is the "initial" state of the variable.

**Therefore, you must initialize the variable to avoid garbage.**

When a variable `x` is declared, it *already* allocates a section to the memory `&x` which is referred by this variable name. Uninitialized values and variables are already placed in a memory address.
Suppose you initialize a variable `v` of type int. It is allocated to a memory address, which is `&v` of type int *. Address `&v` therefore would be placed to an open unused place in the memory.

Consider this code inside a main function:

```
int x; 
// A number of bytes (in this case, sizeof(int), usually 4 B) already allocated
// starting at a memory location &x.

printf("Value at address %p: %d", &x, x); 
// Value at &x may be any int, which is unpredictable
```

When compiling this code, this warning message occurs, where `SOME_DIRECTORY` is an arbitrary directory:

```
SOME_DIRECTORY>gcc -Wall -g sampleprogram.c -o sampleprogram
sampleprogram.c: In function 'main':
sampleprogram.c:8:5: warning: 'x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("Value at address %p: %d", &x, x);
```

The starting value of a memory, just like circuits, is unpredictable. No matter why your value is random garbage. This is also a form of *undefined behavior*, which means that the International Standard of C compilers do not set any requirements so *anything may happen*. This is a very bad bug, can cause multiple hard-to-trace bugs and glitches.

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining local variables then no. The compiler doesn't initialize them for you. The stack grows and shrinks depending on functions being called and their local variables. It doesn't make sense for a compiler to clear all the memory at every function call.

However, global variables can have an initial value of 0 if they are placed in the [.bss](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) this is an optimization to shrink the size of a program.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly want to compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then it is likely that you'll get warnings, and you should improve your code to get none.

Of course, **you should initialize your variables**. BTW, such an initialization is short to code, and runs very quickly. And in several occasions (with e.g. `-O1`) `gcc` is able to optimize (using the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)) and remove useless initializations. So as a rule of thumb don't be scared of "useless" initializations.

You should get the habit to initialize most variables (there are very few exceptions, e.g. the seed of some [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)), actually all of them. In the few cases where you don't initialize a variable on purpose and prefer it to retain some garbage value, document that in a comment (but don't expect that garbage to be really random; it still could in practice be always the same).

Read more about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB.

Remember that variables are names in the source code. Variables don't exist at runtime (only locations exist then). They could be removed by the compiler, they might sometimes sit in some slot of the call frame of the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), they could go in some register, etc...