# typeof() does not work and throws error while compiling

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-settings

I need to work with old project. And somehow it does not allow me to compile with next line:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Though __typeof works. Build settings allows this feature.

[image: Build settings typeof allowed]

Where I need to check it?

Comment: GNU99 dialect allows it.  I don't know what C99 rules say about it.

Comment: @PhillipMills That works. I wonder why C11 standard does not allows it? It should be the most recent.

Comment: I am not a language lawyer but I think it's a GCC extension rather than a part of the C standard...maybe.

Comment: @PhillipMills Well C99 contains __typeof(), and typeof() is just alias for that. Mb I am completely wrong about it.

Comment: @PhillipMills please add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @PhillipMills correctly stated `C99`, as well as `C11`, does not support `typeof`.

To use it without prefix (`__typeof`), it is necessary to use `GNU99` dialect. Here is comprehensive list of differences: [What's the difference between GNU99 and C99 (Clang)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313536/whats-the-difference-between-gnu99-and-c99-clang)

Also, I found out that all Xcode templates use `GNU99` C dialect by default.