# Cool GCC built-ins

Tags: c, gcc

I've heard of a lot of cool GCC extensions and built-in functions over the years, but I always wind up forgetting about them before thinking of using them.

What are some cool GCC extensions and built-ins, and some real-life examples of how to put them to use?

Comment: If you want to write portable code, you will stay away from (gcc) extensions.

Comment: Despite extensions being bad, some builtin functions (with the same names as standard ones) are very useful because they make operations that might seem slow/inefficient actually practical.

Comment: You may also find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375697/useful-gcc-flags-for-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC provides many features as compiler extensions, off the top of mind and frequently used by me are:

**[Statement Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs)**
**[Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits)**

There are many more documented on the GCC website **[here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html)**.

**Caveat:**
However, using any form of compiler extensions renders your code non-portable across other compilers so do use them at that risk.

Comment: seeing designated initializers as an extension is kind of weird, it is part of the standard since C99.. (I know that they phrase this as such)

Comment: Designated initializers are part of the C language, not an extension.

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled over quite a lot of them that are really helpful to emulate the new C11 standard. Actually many of the new features are already there, but with different syntax.

- alignment attributes
- thread local variables
- noreturn attribute to functions
- atomic operations (through their `__sync_...` builtins)
- type generic programming

I've written some of that and how to use that with the C11 interfaces in my [blog](http://gustedt.wordpress.com).

Two features that are not covered in functionality by C11 that are really nice, and that I'd very much like to see in future versions of the standard

- statement expressions (already mentioned by Als)
- `__typeof__`

Answer (score 2):

If you want real-life examples of how useful [gcc extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) can be then [GCC hacks in the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gcc-hacks/) is an interesting choice since if it is being used in the Linux kernel then it is probably a good indication it has some real-world impact. As noted before, using extensions does make your code non-portable but [clang does make an effort to support gcc extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#introduction) which may mitigate some of the impact.

One extensions that is not covered but is used a lot in the Linux kernel is [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), also see [Are compund statements (blocks) surrounded by parens expressions in ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238016/are-compund-statements-blocks-surrounded-by-parens-expressions-in-ansi-c/18885626#18885626).

The article covers the following features:

- Type discovery using [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof)
- Range extension which includes both [Case Ranges](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges) and [Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits)
- [Zero-length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length) are flexible array members but with some additions
- Determining call address using [__builtin_return_addres](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html#Return-Address)
- Constant detection using [__builtin_constant_p](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins)
- [Function Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)
- Branch prediction hints using [__builtin_expect](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins)
- Pre-fetching using [__builtin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins)
- [Variable attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes)