# What are some of the most commonly used gcc/g++ flags for information (not just optimization)

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

I have found -E very useful to see preprocessor output and debug macros, and I have seen -fdump-class-hierarchy to look at the v-tables of a class hierarchy...I know there are flags to dump asm output as well..what are some other widely (or perhaps a bit unknown but very handy) flags akin to these?

Comment: Take a look at this [Useful GCC flags for C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375697/useful-gcc-flags-for-c), even though it says C, most of it applies to g++ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few flags which I like:

`-x language`: used to compile file with extension other than .c or .cpp

`-s` - dump asm.

`-g` - debug build.

`gcc -O3 -Q --help=optimizers | grep disabled` - will give you all optimization flags which remain diabled even after `-O3`

[Wonderful place for all wonderful options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)