# Inverted arguments in scanf()

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I was (quickly) writing some code and accidently inverted the arguments in `scanf()`:

```
char i[] = "ABC1\t";
scanf(i, "%s");
```

Compiling with `gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra` doesn't complain about this one bit. Obviously, this code doesn't work, but why didn't gcc inform me that I inverted the arguments? Can't it detect that `i` is not a format string, or that the second argument was not a store-able type?

**EDIT**
Thanks for the insight all, Looks like I found the answer, there was a twist on the `-Wformat` flag that makes this "catchable" (posted it below for reference)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ha! I found it. Hitting gcc with the `-Wformat=2` flag caught it.

Posting the info for reference of others:

Here's the [list of flags I found](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

`-Wformat
Check calls to printf and scanf, etc., to make sure that the arguments supplied have types appropriate to the format string specified...`

I had assumed `-Wall` had `-Wformat` in it, which it does, but the really important part about what I just found:

`-Wformat is included in -Wall. For more control over some aspects of format checking, the options -Wformat-y2k, -Wno-format-extra-args, -Wno-format-zero-length, -Wformat-nonliteral, -Wformat-security, and -Wformat=2 are available, but are not included in -Wall.`

Comment: Yeah, +1  I was also looking for it.\

Answer (score 8):

I suppose it shouldn't.

```
int scanf ( const char * format, ... );
```

`i` was normally converted to a `const char*`, all the rest parameters are just "ellipsis" and cannot be checked at compile time.

Comment: The headers used by GCC usually have the first parameter marked as a format string and then it can ensure that the correct types are passed to the remaining parameters, provided `-Wformat` is provided. I believe this is part of `-Wall`.

Comment: @Will But then again - a non-const char* was passed as a format string (which is valid by itself) and so compiler did not force parameter check. It might have done so if format string was `const char*` or literal.

Comment: Probably it does not check between 'char* fmt' & 'const char* fmt'. Can anyone tell, if the second argument ("ABC\t") will be char* or const char*?

Comment: EDIT:
Probably it does not check between 'char* fmt' & 'const char* fmt'. Can anyone tell, if the second argument ("ABC\t") will be char* or const char*? btw, 2nd argument will be completely ignores, because the format string does not contain any % format character.

Comment: The thing is that glibc defines `scanf` with `__attribute__((format(scanf, 1, 2)))` which is a gcc option to tell it to check the arguments and issue a warning. Otherwise, it is obvious that the question doesn't have a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 3):

The manual entry for scanf (man scanf) gives the prototype:

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

A char[] is just a special type of char *, so the first argument is satisfied. Secondary arguments are evaluated at runtime (if I recall), so they aren't even considered by the compiler here. From the compiler's prospective, this is a fine call to the function given its prototype.

Also, the compiler never checks whether you are trying to write to invalid locations. The great (or terrible) thing about C is that it will let you do more or less what you want, even if what you want is a bad idea.

Comment: It is true that `scanf` by itself accepts these, but in glibc, compiled with gcc, scanf has `__attribute__((format(scanf, 1, 2)))` which tells the compiler to make sure the parameters are correct, even though this is not enforced by the declaration of `scanf`.