# how to make gcc ftrapv work?

Tags: c, gcc

I am compiling the code below as

```
$ gcc -Wall  -ftrapv test.c
```

However running the generated executable always prints-2147483648 which is not what I expected. I am running gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5).

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <limits.h>
  4 #include <signal.h>
  5 
  6 void h(int signal)
  7 {
  8         printf("caught signal exiting\n");
  9         exit(1);
 10 }
 11 
 12 int main(void)
 13 {
 14         int x = INT_MAX;
 15         int y;
 16 
 17         signal(SIGABRT,h);
 18         y = x+1;
 19         printf("%d\n",y);
 20         return 0;
 21 }
```

Added later: compiling with clang and changing SIGABRT to SIGILL works, but no luck with gcc so far.

Comment: My understanding (but I can't find the reference in the GCC docs right now, so this is a comment not an answer) is that `-ftrapv` does not work in GCC, and perhaps never worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `-ftrapv` support in GCC is somewhat broken, they have an [open bug, Bug-35412](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35412) in their Bugzilla from 2008 it seems in order to cover it.

Comment: Can you add the reference to the bug ? Thank you.

Comment: The recommended alternative nowadays is a variant of `-fsanitize=undefined` (`-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error` for instance).