# Why do C variables maximum and minimum values touch?

Tags: c, variables

I am working on a tutorial for binary numbers.  Something I have wondered for a while is why all the integer maximum and minimum values touch.  For example for an unsigned byte 255 + 1 = 0 and 0 - 1 = 255.  I understand all the binary math that goes into it, but why was the decision made to have them work this way instead of a straight number line that gives an error when the extremes are breached?

Comment: because the size of the variable types are fixed?

Comment: and FWIW, signed integer overflow is UB....

Comment: Perhaps ask this in context of Java or C#, which have very defined wrapping behavior. (C# also supports a [checked integer mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) which *would* throw an exception.)

Comment: If you phrase the question as "Why not always check for overflow, even when there's no need to do so?" the answer becomes obvious.

Comment: Think about the odometer on your car - when it gets to 999999 what happens next ?

Comment: I do not know the specific answer.
But from a hardware point of view, creating an error flag was an extra overhead. Nevertheless, accumulators in processors, does give flags when an overflow occurs. It seems, C chose to ignore that. Perhaps, it is because some program may use this barrel roll feature in their computation. Or, probably the flags are available in C for the programmer to check.

Comment: The UB behavior of C allows a valid C program to work the same across hardware (or rather, it says that an UB/non-valid program can "do anything" (in reality programs can and do take advantage of 'behavior on a specific target')) - the target may use different sizes of native integers (including in any intermediate calculations), or even 1's vs 2's complement differences. Claiming UB allows the constraints (and thus additional checks or de-ops) on implementation to be relaxed.

Comment: @ponir C does not ignore processor overflow flags when making a comparison. There is no reason for C to do anything different than the assembler comparisons which consider the overflow flag, since C compiler knows the context of signed/unsigned tests even though that choice in assembler is left to the coder.

Comment: @TomK that decision was made - or not made - because C does **not** check for value overflow or array bounds. Instead, the rules of C leave that as *undefined behaviour* except for documented instances, for example `unsigned` integers which will wrap round reliably.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Unsigned integers cannot overflow and there is no overflow flag in C. Signed integer overflow is UB (I know you know), so also no need for overflow flag here. The flag in the CPU is just used to determine the result of a comparison, but not a necessary feature.

Comment: @ponir: No, C defines it for unsigned integers intentionally the way it does. For signed, it is UB because not all CPUs provide an overflow flag.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for restating my comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane: believe it or not, I did not see your last comment when I wrote mine. Maybe I forgot a refresh or so.

Answer (score 8):

Since your example is unsigned, I assume it's OK to limited the scope to unsigned types.

Allowing wrapping is useful. For example, it's what allows you (and the compiler) to always reorder (and constant-fold) a sequence of additions and subtractions. Even something such as `x + 3 - 1` could not be optimized to `x + 2` if the language requires trapping, because it changes the conditions under which the expression would trap. Wrapping also mixes better with bit manipulation, with the interpretation of an unsigned number as a vector of bits it makes very little sense if there's trapping. That applies especially to shifts, but addition, subtraction and even multiplication also make sense on bitvectors and combine usefully with the usual bitwise operations.

The algebraic structure you get when allowing wrapping, Z/2<sup>k</sup>Z, is fairly nice (perhaps not as nice as modulo a prime, but that would interact badly with the bitvector interpretation and it doesn't match typical hardware) and well known, so it's not like anything particularly unexpected or weird will happen, it's not like a wrapped result is a "uselessly arbitrary" result.

And of course testing the carry flag (or whatever may be required) after just about every operation has a big direct overhead as well.

Trapping on "unsigned overflow" is both expensive and undesirable, at least if it is the default behaviour.

Comment: Also allows say a 256-element ring buffer to be indexed by `uint8_t` and wrap naturally.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Or, to use a real-world analog, if a vehicle's odometer reads 99,975 before a day trip and it reads 00,025 after, one can tell that the vehicle traveled 50 miles on that trip (the reading would be the same after 100,050 miles, but traveling that far in a day would be implausible).  Having the odometer peg at 99,999 would make it less useful.

Comment: @supercat looking at the question title, I don't think the max and min values are required to touch for *signed* integer types, as pointed out by Lundin in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965521/example-2-1-kr-wrong-symbolic-constants-value-for-long-min-and-long-max/37965633#37965633) and wrapping in that case is UB anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Given the rationale for having short unsigned types promote to signed, the authors of the C89 Standard clearly expected that the majority of C implementations would interpret signed addition, subtraction, and multiplication as yielding results equivalent to unsigned unless the result exceeded the common range of both types *and* the result was promoted, used as the left operand of `>>`, or used as either operand of `%`, `/`, or a comparison operator; I see no reason to believe they didn't intend that to remain true forever.  That does not imply that...

Comment: @supercat another example is when checking time intervals from an unsigned timer counter value. Comparing the present timer with a mark can fail unless you make the subtraction first and then compare for the required interval. Of course like your odometer exmaple, it can only wrap once.

Comment: ...they would have expected implementations to truncate operations on `int` types to the range of `int` after every step, though I doubt many would oppose the idea that a *good* implementation on a two's-complement system should interpret `(int)(x+y)` as equivalent to `(int)((unsigned)x+y)` [the cast serving the same role as e.g. `double d1 = (float)(f1+f2);` [without the cast, a compiler might--depending upon FLT_EVAL_METHOD, do the addition as type `double` and store the full double result, but the cast would force the result to be reduced to `float` precision].

Answer (score 1):

Why not "give an error when the extremes are breached"?

Error handling is one of the hardest things in software development. When an error happens, there are many possible ways software could be required to do:

- Show an annoying message to the user? Like `Hey user, you have just tried to add 1 to this variable, which is already too big. Stop that!` - there often is no context to show the user, that would be of any help.
- Throw an exception? (BTW [C has support for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20851061/509868)) - that would show a stack trace, if you happened to execute your code in a debugger. Otherwise, it would just crash - not bad (it won't corrupt your files) but not good either (can be exploited as a denial of service attack).
- Write it to a log file? - sometimes it's the best thing to do - record the error and move on, so it can be debugged later.

The right thing to do depends on your code. So a generic programming language like C doesn't want to restrict you by providing any mandatory behavior.

---

Instead, C provides two guidelines:

- For unsigned types like `unsigned int` or `uint8_t` or (usually) `char` - it provides silent wraparound, for best performance.
- For signed types like `int` - it provides "undefined behavior", which makes it possible to "choose", in a very limited way, what will happen on overflow

  - [Throw an exception](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) if using `-ftrapv` in gcc
  - Silent wraparound if using `-fwrapv` in gcc
  - By default (no fancy command-line options) - the compiler may assume it will never happen, [which may help it produce optimized code](http://kristerw.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/how-undefined-signed-overflow-enables.html)

The idea here is that you (the programmer) should think where checking for overflow is worth doing, and *how to recover from overflow* (if the language provided a standard error handling mechanism, it would deny you the latter part). This approach has maximum flexibility, (potentially) maximum performance, and (usually) hardest to do - which fits the philosophy of C.

Comment: _undefined behaviour_ is not a feature of the language, but once invoked you have left the standard. Anything can happen and there are no guarantees by the language anymore. General advice: avoid under all circumstances (unless you really, really, really know the implementation and the language, know 100% what goes on and have absolutely no other choice). The rest is not part of the standard (please provide a reference where the standard mentions command line options).

Comment: Undefined behaviour, in my opinion, absolutely **is** a feature of the language! Look - it's all over the spec! Stuff like `-ftrapv` is not a feature of the language, but it's a documented feature of the compiler, which I can rely on.

Comment: This is about the language, not a specific implementation. And, no, UB is not a feature of the language, but that the standard does not define the behaviour, thus you are in terra incognita: hic sunt dracones (or nasal daemons)! Read the standard, it provides a definition of UB in the intro.

Comment: @Olaf cannot resist quirking your "provides a definition of UB"

Comment: @WeatherVane: Feel free to, on a secod read, I do, too:-) Of course I mean "provides a definition of the phrase "undefined behaviour"