# Example 2.1, K&R: Wrong symbolic constants value for LONG_MIN and LONG_MAX?

Tags: c++, c, kernighan-and-ritchie

This is the code which I use to find the symbolic constant values for LONG

```
   #include <limits.h>     //These header files contains the symbolic constants
   #include <float.h>      //for different datatypes

   #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void){

            printf("\tMininum numeric value for long type: %ld\n", LONG_MIN);
            printf("\tMaximum numeric value for long type: %ld\n", LONG_MAX);

            printf("\tMaximum numeric value for unsigned long type: %lu\n", (unsigned)ULONG_MAX);
    return 0;
   }
```

Output which I get is:

```
  Mininum numeric value for long type: -9223372036854775808
  Maximum numeric value for long type: 9223372036854775807
  Maximum numeric value for unsigned long type: 4294967295
```

But if see the limits.h from the man page. These are the symbolic constants for `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN` and `LLONG_MAX` from the `limits.h` file in my system.

```
  {LONG_MIN}
          Minimum value of type long.
          Maximum Acceptable Value: -2 147 483 647

  {LONG_MAX}
          Maximum value of a long.
          Minimum Acceptable Value: +2 147 483 647

  {LLONG_MIN}
          Minimum value of type long long.
          Maximum Acceptable Value: -9223372036854775807

  {LLONG_MAX}
          Maximum value of type long long.
          Minimum Acceptable Value: +9223372036854775807
```

As if, the program is giving me the values from Long long symbolic constants.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are casting `ULONG_MAX` to `unsigned`, which is not large enough to hold the value (on your system). No cast is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, why do you tag this question as c++ when you are citing K&R examples?  Please, don't mesh languages.  Take the c++ tag off from here, please.

Answer (score 2):

The size of types are variable. A `long` is *at least* 32 bits (which gives the +-2 billion range), but it's allowed to be larger. On a 64 bit system it might, for example, be 64 bits.

A `long long` must be at least 64 bits, but may of course be larger.

These sizes depend on the underlying hardware platform *and* the compiler. For example on Windows 64-bit system using GCC then `long` is 64 bits but using the Visual C++ compiler `long` is "only" 32 bits.

Read more about [integer types in this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Integer_types).

Comment: Ok, but then why am I getting the 32 bit value for the unsigned long?

Comment: @hsuyaa Because you cast it to an `unsigned int` (`unsigned` is short for `unsigned int` because `int` is the "default" integer type), which is typically 32 bits. If you want an `unsigned long` you should cast it as such.

Comment: Thanks!  
Can we cast the result to the unsigned long?

Comment: @hsuyaa Yes you should.

Comment: @hsuyaa, You're also using `%lu` to print the `unsigned` instead of `%u`, so it's anyone's guess what will happen. I recommend [compiler warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0782f0e1be47972d).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `long` is 64 bits on your system.

The C standard specifies *minimum limits* for integer types. Meaning that for example LONG_MAX has to be *at least* `2 147 483 647`, but it could be larger.

As a side note, this is a bug: `(unsigned)ULONG_MAX`. Should be unsigned long.

---

One interesting curiousity: note for example that LONG_MIN has to be at least `-2 147 483 647`. But even on a regular 32 bit two complement system, it never has that value!
It has the value `-2 147 483 648`. This is done intentionally to allow one's complement and sign & magnitude systems.

Comment: It's also curious that MSVC has `#define LONG_MIN (-2147483647L - 1)` which is done that way to prevent the compiler complaining about `2147483648L` being out of range (before the negation).

Comment: @WeatherVane Well I guess that's yet another design flaw in C... there exist no negative literals before you apply the unary minus operator on them.

Answer (score 0):

It's what it says.

> ```
> Minimum Acceptable Value: +2 147 483 647
> ```

The "minimum acceptable value" for `LONG_MAX` is that. Your value for `LONG_MAX` (because your system is 64-bit) is higher.

So there's no problem.