# This code is for printing an array in reverse order in C. But it is not working

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rev_array(int array[],  int n);

int main(){

    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of elements in the array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int array[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Enter the element %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    rev_array(array[n], n);
    return 0;
}

void rev_array(int array[],  int n){
    for(int i=(n-1); i>-1; i--){
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

This error is coming when I try to run the code

Test_Code.c: In function 'main':
Test_Code.c:17:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'rev_array' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
rev_array(array[n], n);
^~~~~
Test_Code.c:3:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
void rev_array(int array[],  int n);
^~~~~~~~~

Comment: `array[n]` is a single element of the array (and one that is out of bounds). You need to pass a pointer to the first element, which is plain `array`.

Comment: ...as the compiler warning points out.

Comment: I have seen this misunderstanding a few times, can you please explain why you thought that `array[i]` is a single element while `array[n]` is the whole array? Why do you think those two expression would mean different things? If we understand why you thought that, then we might be able to better explain it for others making the same mistake.

Comment: Be aware that even if the compiler tells you this is "only" a warning, warnings with the wording "makes pointer from integer without a cast" are almost always errors and should be treated as such.

Comment: At this stage in your programming career, if the compiler rings to give you a warning, it means thee is a big in your code that needs to be fixed.  Given that you’re using GCC, you should be using `GCC -Werror -Wall -Wextra -std=c18 -pedantic` as the compiler options — you could be fussier, but that’s a good start.

Comment: Regarding the warning, what where your own thoughts about the warning when you read it? What did you think it meant?

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace

```
    rev_array(array[n], n);
```

with:

```
    rev_array(array, n);
```

Because the function rev_array() first argument is an array of type int while you passed the n th element of the array instead.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

As suggested by [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), the error in your code is that you're passing an **element** of the array (`array[n]`), instead of the array itself (`array`), to a function that expects a pointer to integer (`void rev_array(int array[], int n)`).

To fix your code you just have to change

```
rev_array(array[n], n);
```

to

```
rev_array(array, n);
```

---

### Note 1

The compiler already tells you why your code can't be compiled:

```
Compiler stderr
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:18:20: warning: passing argument 1 of 'rev_array' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   18 |     rev_array(array[n], n);
      |               ~~~~~^~~
      |                    |
      |                    int
<source>:3:20: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'
    3 | void rev_array(int array[],  int n);
      |                ~~~~^~~~~~~
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375697/what-are-the-useful-gcc-flags-for-c) for some useful flags to get more warning/errors.

---

### Note 2

In general you shouldn't rely on variable length arrays (such as `array[n]`, where you read `n` through `scanf()`), since not every C Standard support them *by default*. Many compilers do, but the best approach, a part from simple exercises like this, is to use [dynamic memory allocation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/) which is made just for this task.

---

### Note 3

Always check `scanf()` and `fscanf()` return value to prevent [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From the **current C Programming Language Standard** - [ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf):

> The fscanf function reads input from the stream pointed to by stream, under control of the string pointed to by format that specifies the admissible input sequences and how they are to be converted for assignment, using subsequent arguments as pointers to the objects to receive the converted input. **If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined**. If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

Comment: I disagree with Note 2. In C23, the support for VLAs will be mandatory again, except that such arrays may have to be dynamically allocated.  It’s a good idea to check that the size is sane, too.  But that is more nuanced than is sensible for this answer.