# Using 'g++' results in "warning: will never be executed"

Tags: c++, gcc-warning, gcc4

I inherited a C++ project. I'm building in [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 5.5 with GCC 4.1.2 via a makefile. The project is huge (hundreds of files) and in general the code is pretty good. However, every so often during compilation I get a GCC warning that says (prefix "`/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2`"):

```
/bits/allocator.h: In constructor ‘std::allocator<_Alloc>::allocator() [with _Tp = char]’:
/bits/allocator.h:97: warning: will never be executed
/bits/allocator.h:97: warning: will never be executed
/ext/new_allocator.h: In constructor ‘__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::new_allocator() [with _Tp = char]’:
/ext/new_allocator.h:65: warning: will never be executed
/bits/allocator.h: In destructor ‘std::allocator<_Alloc>::~allocator() [with _Tp = char]’:
/bits/allocator.h:105: warning: will never be executed
/ext/new_allocator.h: In destructor ‘__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::~new_allocator() [with _Tp = char]’:
/ext/new_allocator.h:72: warning: will never be executed
/bits/allocator.h: In copy constructor ‘std::allocator<_Alloc>::allocator(const std::allocator<_Alloc>&) [with _Tp = char]’:
/bits/allocator.h:100: warning: will never be executed
/bits/allocator.h:99: warning: will never be executed
/ext/new_allocator.h: In copy constructor ‘__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::new_allocator(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = char]’:
/ext/new_allocator.h:67: warning: will never be executed
/bits/allocator.h: In destructor ‘std::allocator<_Alloc>::~allocator() [with _Tp = char]’:
/bits/allocator.h:105: warning: will never be executed
```

It doesn't give me the source file or line number that the error is originating from. I'm going to go out on a limb and say the headers for GCC are just fine, so what is going on here? I've never encountered this particular warning before.

Comment: Off-topic: googling "warning: will never be executed __gnu_cxx::new_allocator" returned this page as the second result.  *Head asplode*

Comment: @Bribles and the first result returns a [gcc bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46158) indicating that "-Wunreachable-code is broken and has been removed from GCC 4.5.". It is advised to remove this warning option from CXXFLAGS.

Comment: @harpun Your google-fu is strong! I actually didn't put two and two together and realize the error was the result of a CXXFLAG option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [GCC bug 46158](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46158), [`-Wunreachable-code`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunreachable_002dcode-437) has always been broken and has been removed since GCC 4.5.

It's very likely that your problem is actually not a problem. (Personally, I'd still consider a newer `gcc`/`g++` unless there are special reasons to use 4.1.2 - it is nearly 6 years old.)

Comment: Upgrading gcc is on the list. I figured getting the project environment setup with a known working configuration was a good first step. I'll be curious to see what other "fun" problems I run into with a gcc upgrade though.

Comment: `-Wunreachable-code` has been [listed as a dummy switch since GCC 4.6](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings/blob/master/gcc/warnings-gcc-4.6.txt#L136) (GCC 4.6.0 [was released](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) on 2011-03-25).

Comment: Though [the latest version in the documentation is GCC 4.4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunreachable_002dcode-437), before GCC 4.5 (not 4.6). GCC 4.4.7 was released 2012-03-13 ([time overlap](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) with the 4.5.x series).

Answer (score 3):

[Bug report 46158](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46158) says at the bottom:

> -Wunreachable-code is broken and has been removed from GCC 4.5.  Do not use it.

So ignoring the warnings doesn't sound like an entirely bad idea.