# Recommended GCC release build flags

Tags: c++, gcc

I use custom make files for my C++ projects.   I am looking for the most recommended compilation flags for release builds.  I am currently using the following:

CXXFLAGS += [-O3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O3) [-Wall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall) [-DNDEBUG](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1)

I thought the above was sufficient, but then I tried to run the 'strip' tool on the binary, and it shrank the size quite a bit.  It looks like there is still some non-essential stuff in the binary.

I know this is a broad topic, but I am looking for common settings for optimal (speed and size) release builds.  I know that gcc by default doesn't even discard dead code—I'd like to figure out how to do that soon.

For reference my, the Make setup is [on GitHub](https://github.com/YasserAsmi/buildmk).

Comment: Related: *"[Recommended GCC warning options for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c)"* and *"[What are the useful GCC flags for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375697/what-are-the-useful-gcc-flags-for-c)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, stripping after linking will remove global symbols that are included from the C++ library, for example. You can get `g++` to do that by using the [-s](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-s) option. It does make debugging the application at a customer site (e.g., telling the customer to run `gdb myprog` and then do `bt` when it's crashed will not give you any symbols → much harder to find out where the code was, unless you have an identical binary with symbols (or can reproduce one), and you can find the symbols in that (or you can reproduce the problem, but that's wishful thinking a lot of the time)).

If you want small code, you can also use the [-Os](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-Os) instead of -O3—that will make the compiler generate optimised code, but not make optimisations that make the code larger (so only inline tiny functions, not unroll loops, etc.). For *some* cases, small code actually runs faster than "higher optimisation" level but larger code, because medium-sized functions that are called in many places are left as a single function, which is in the cache, rather than being inlined and bloating the application.

Unfortunately it is often hard to say for sure what effect any particular options have on the size of the executable - in some cases, inlining makes for smaller code, other cases it makes the code longer. Unrolling a loop with a count of 2 makes for shorter code than doing the same thing in a loop, etc, etc. If you want fast and small code, you will have to fiddle around with settings and see which ones have what effect on *your* code. Make sure you keep track of what effect you get from each option. There are quite a few different optimisation options, listed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) (that's for 4.9.1, and you can find online versions of older manuals too on the GCC site).

Comment: Thanks Mats!  Very helpful.  I didn't realize the symbol table was the thing that getting stripped.  That makes sense.  Also -Os is something I haven't tried.

Comment: Well, `-s` will do, more or less, the same thing as `strip`, so don't expect it to "do magic". But it's a step less than first running the compiler, then running `strip` on the resulting binary. On the other hand, `strip` does have a bunch of controls that allow you to adjust exactly what you remove (if you just run `strip` with no options, it will remove "everything") - and you can also use `strip` to remove sections from a file, for example - but only do that if you REALLY know what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant -Os (was a typo I edited).  Makes sense about -s being same more less same as strip.  I don't actually plan to use strip (I don't want to make my life harder :))

Comment: Something seems to be missing after *"customer site"*. It could be *"harder"* or *"more difficult"*.

Comment: Re *"listed here ... that's for 4.9.1..."*: There is [a generic page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for the latest (current) [GCC version](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html). The version-dependent pages are usually only needed for removed or changed options, like  *[-Wunreachable-code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunreachable_002dcode-437)*, *[-fmudflap](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fmudflap-765)*, -

Comment: cont' - *[-combine](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-combine-82)*, and *[-df](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-df-499)*. (The links are to the latest release they appeared in.)

Answer (score 4):

```
CXXFLAGS += -O3 -Wall -DNDEBUG
```

Is fine.   Assuming NDEBUG is used, I never use that personally.
If you need a smaller binary, use the [-s](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-s) strip symbol table option which is similar to what strip would do.  Generally, I don't bother and leave the symbol table there as it can still be useful.