# glibc function strtoull() failure

Tags: c, string, glibc

I am facing issue with c library function strtoull which is returning me wrong output.

```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
    unsigned long long int intValue;

    if(atoi(argv[2]) == 1)
    {   
        intValue = strtoull((const char *)argv[1], 0, 10 );
    }
    else
    {
//  ...
    }

    printf("intValue of %s is %llu \n", argv[1], intValue);

    return 0;
    }
```

I built them and generated 32 and 64 bit executables as str32_new and str64_new.
But the output received from 32 bit exe is errorneous as wrong number is returned:

strtoull should had returned me number 5368709120 for the passed string "5368709120" but it returned me 1073741824.

```
# ./str32_new "5368709120" 1
intValue of 5368709120 is 1073741824
```

I note that when I decrease one character from string then it shows proper output.

```
# ./str32_new "536870912" 1
intValue of 536870912 is 536870912
```

glibc attached to 32 bit exe is

```
   # readelf -Wa /home/str32_new | grep strt
  [39] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 002545 000190 00      0   0  1
  [41] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 0032f8 0002a4 00      0   0  1
  0804a014  00000607 R_386_JUMP_SLOT        00000000   strtoull
     6: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strtoull@GLIBC_2.0 (2)
    55: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS strtoull.c
    75: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strtoull@@GLIBC_2.0
    77: 08048534   915 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 my_strtoull
```

glibc attached to 64 bit exe is

```
 # readelf -Wa /home/str64_new | grep strt
  [39] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 001893 000192 00      0   0  1
  [41] .strtab           STRTAB          0000000000000000 002cd0 00029b 00      0   0  1
  0000000000601028  0000000700000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT     0000000000000000 strtoull + 0
     7: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strtoull@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
    57: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS strtoull.c
    73: 00000000004006cc   804 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 my_strtoull
    82: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND strtoull@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

64 bit exe shows proper output but on some system it too behaves abnormally.
Why is the strtoull in 32 bit exe behaving so and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: 5368709120 & (0xffffffff) = 1073741824

Comment: Your code does `#include <stdlib.h>`, doesn't it?

Comment: no I did not.
Including it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so we've established that this is quite obviously happening due to an overflow, as the value matches what would happen if casted into 32bit int.

This however does not explain everything - you did use strtoull, not the shorter strtoul, and it indeed works on 64bit binary. If anything, I was surprised to see you were even able to call the longer version in your 32bit build (how did you build it by the way, with -m32? or on a special machine?)

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646031/strtoull-and-long-long-arithmetic), raises the possibility that there's some linkage phenomenon that makes strtoull get declared as `int strtoll()` (presumably the system can't support the original lib version), and so we get the value implicitly casted through int, before copied back to your unsigned long long.

Either way - this should have been warned against by the compiler, try setting it to c99 and raise the warning levels, maybe that would make it shout

Comment: Agreed. It might even be something as silly as not including headers for printf, and parameter being downcasted to int.

Comment: I had not included stdlib.h.
Including it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is due to overflow. `int` in 32bit can not hold a number that large (max is `4294967296`). As Leeor said, `5368709120 & (0xffffffff) = 1073741824`.

The type `int` is minimally 32 bits wide, and is only 32 bits wide on most (if not all) systems.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` and you probably did not enable any compiler warnings (like for using undeclared functions).

When a C compiler sees a function call to an undeclared function it blindly assumes `int f(int)` as prototype. In your case the return value of `strtoull()` will be int and so the value will be truncated to 32-bit.

(It is indeed quite strange that you get the correct result on a 64-bit system, where int is usually also just 32-bit.)