# Convert a string to a unsigned long long in c++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Convert a string to a unsigned long long.

```
string str = "0x1232"
```

How do I convert to a unsigned long long.

This is what i've tried.

```
unsigned long long ull;
ull = stoull(str, NULL, 0);
```

Error:

```
 error: identifier "stoull" is undefined
                        ull = stoull(str, NULL, 0);
```

Can you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all it's [`strtoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) (notice the `r`). Second of all, it's an old C-style function and can't handle `std::string` directly. You either have to pass it `str.c_str()` or use the new [`std::stoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul).

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @pistal, Here's one for `std::stoi`, which is really close to `std::stoull`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: I get the following error:

error: namespace "std" has no member "stoull"
                        ull = std::stoull(str,NULL,16);

Comment: @pistal Then your compiler is to old and don't have the C++11 `std::stoull`. You have to use `strtoull`, but change the argument accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried the following:
error: no instance of function "strtoull" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::string, long, int)
                        ull = strtoull(str,NULL,10);

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1646085/2015933

Comment: @pistal Please read my answer again, it contains the solution to that too.

Comment: I have used strtoull.. and not stoull. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @pistal The problem is that `strtoull` is an old C-style function, that takes a `const char*` argument and not `std::string`.

Comment: So, Should I use str.c_str() instead? Could you point me to an examle or give me one?

Comment: @pistal Yes that's correct. Just e.g. `ull = std::strtoull(str.c_str(), 0, 16);`