# Bad conversion from gchar* to guint64 on android

Tags: c, android-ndk, gstreamer

I am writing a c project for PC and Android, and in some place I have to convert from a gchar* to a guint64 value. On the PC project (ubuntu, eclipse, gstreamer1.6.3) it does the conversion successfully. But using the same code into the android project (ubuntu, android-studio, ndk10, gstreamer1.6.3) is not working right. The instruction I am using on both projects is:

```
guint64 val = (guint64) strtoull(char_val, (char**)NULL, 10);
```

Has anyone any clue why it is not working properly on android?

Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646031/strtoull-and-long-long-arithmetic) asks "Do you have <stdlib.h> included?"

Comment: Oh you are right, thanks!

Comment: No compiler warning, or not enabled? They *do* matter.

Comment: @user4467097 If that solved the problem, I'll close this as a duplicate. If not, please leave a comment including `@Lundin` and I'll un-close.