# GCC options for strictest C code?

Tags: c, gcc, iso, strict, ansi-c

What GCC options should be set to have GCC as strict as possible? (and I do mean as strict as possible) I'm writing in C89 and want my code to be ANSI/ISO compliant.

Comment: For strictest you should be clear which standard you are targeting. ANSI X3.159-1989 and/or ISO/IEC 9899:1990, ISO/IEC 9899:1999, or "C1X" from ISO/IEC working group (http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14) (JTC1/SC22/WG14). ANSI C and ISO C90 only differ in the section numbering of the standard itself AFAIK

Comment: @mctylr: "I'm writing in C89" seems perfectly clear.

Comment: Strictly speaking, C89 is not ANSI/ISO compliant.  The current ISO C standard is the one published in 2011; that's also the current ANSI C standard; the 1989, 1990, and 1999 standards are officially obsolete.  But that's just a quibble over wording; there's still widespread support for C89/C90 (more than for C99), and you can still conform to it even if it's no longer an official standard.

Comment: @KeithThompson I wasn't sure if there was an implicit _latest_ as in "... want my code to be _latest_ ANSI/ISO standard complaint".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'd recommend using:

```
-Wall -Wextra -std=c89 -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition
```

You should compile with `-O` as well as `-g` as some warnings are only available when the optimizer is used (actually, I usually use `-O3` for spotting the problems).  You might prefer `-std=gnu89` as that disables fewer extensions in the libraries.  OTOH, if you're coding to strict ANSI C89, maybe you want them disabled.  The `-ansi` option is equivalent to `-std=c89` but not quite as explicit or flexible.

The missing prototypes warns you about functions which are used (or external functions defined) without a prototype in scope.  The strict prototypes means you can't use 'empty parentheses' for function declarations or definitions (or function pointers); you either need `(void)` or the correct argument list.  The old style definition spots K&R style function definitions, such as:

```
int old_style(a, b) int a; double b; { ... }
```

If you're lucky, you won't need to worry about that.  I'm not so lucky at work, and I can't use strict prototypes, much to my chagrin, because there are too many sloppy function pointers around.

See also: [What is the best command-line tool to clean up code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393208/what-is-the-best-command-line-tool-to-clean-up-code/)

Comment: The `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition` options are a good idea, but they don't address standard conformance.  Old-style function declarations and definitions have been obsolescent since 1989, but they're still part of the language; even C2011-conforming compilers are required to support them.

Comment: @Keith: you have the `-pedantic` flag turned on in your reading :D  Yes, but I still recommend using the options so that the code is maximally forward-portable to later versions of the standard.  It would not surprise me to find that C2021 finally loses standard support for non-prototype functions, though implementations will likely continue to support the old notations for another 10-20 years after that.  C11 also eliminates `gets()`; I don't expect it to vanish from libraries for a long time either.  It should be avoided, even though it is fully C89 compliant.

Comment: I wrote a post on this: http://shitalshah.com/p/how-to-enable-and-use-gcc-strict-mode-compilation/

Comment: @ShitalShah: Interesting.  Your blog is about C++ rather than C, but that's OK.  I'm puzzled about the 'ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used' message (especially in a C++ compilation).  I'm not clear what that means.  Is it related to the `__VA_ARGS__` macro — it must be used somewhere?  Or is it something else.  I looked at the bug report and frankly wasn't enlightened about the change that was required.

Answer (score 9):

This set of options is pretty good:

```
-Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic
```

You'll have to read the documentation to see if there are any extra warnings getting left out by that combination.

You should be warned that strict C89 doesn't include support for `//` style comments, and there are some pretty serious restrictions on the number of significant characters in the names of objects with external linkage.

Comment: Documentation says that "-ansi -pedantic" should get you strict ISO C90, and will warn on ANY GNU C extension (not just those that are incompatible). You can use "-pedantic-errors" if you want errors. Though not really an issue of strictness, you can consider "-Werror" which will turn warnings into errors. Though philosophically "Warnings are not Errors"