# Does anyone use the clang static analyzer for C/objective-C? Is it good or not?

Tags: c, code-analysis

I am aware of a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145191/static-code-analyzers-for-c) where someone mentioned the [clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) but gave no further comments. Most of answers pointed to the lint family which disappointed me from time to time due to the bulk of false positives.

I noticed the clang static analyzer when I read XCode release notes. I have tried it and it only produced one false positive out of ~20,000 lines from several projects. The logic behind that false positive is a bit complicated which fools the analyzer. But what about false negatives? Will clang static analyzer miss a lot of potential errors? Does anyone has more experience? More generally, does static analyzer really help to reduce bugs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just read about this on one of the blogs I follow a few months back. I've been reading this guys blog since about December of 2008. He had a really great review/tutorial on using the static analyzer. [Check it out](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/clang-static-analyzer.html).

Comment: Actually I more like to see an article comparing clang and lint. However, I guess few people are using static analyzers. Anyway, the link you provide is helpful when few articles are around. Thanks.